# June 2023 Data Dump is missing

Tags: support, status-completed, data-dump

The [data dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) usually gets refreshed the first weekend of the month, every 3 months.

The current data dump is still from March. Is there just a problem and it's delayed like [in the past](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377171/waiting-for-march-2022-dump)?

---

<sup>Relevant company information is revealed in the answers by former employee [AMtwo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390023/), then by current employees [Jody Bailey](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390040/), and finally by [Philippe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390200/).</sup>

Comment: If the data was published it might make it easier to debunk the nonsense...

Comment: I don't think it was ever done on time. It's a very complex process, hence always failing at some point. I consider it a miracle when it's actually working and there is actually a data dump. (Kind of like launching a spaceship.)

Comment: @ShadowWizardStrikesBack rude...I disagree that it was never done on time. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizardStrikesBack I can confirm it has been frequently late since Taryn left.  The upload to the Archive would frequently hang and need baby sitting. That said, we actually resolved that recently, so the data dump wouldn't be late anymore.

Comment: I'm hoping someone from the Company gives an official response soon. Having been recently laid off, I'm not in a position to give a complete/official answer here... But if there's no official response soon, I'll jump in with what I can offer.

Comment: @RoryAlsop the data dump is just a full export of [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com). You're limited by the tooling for timeouts, and doing the analysis in SQL Server, but there's at least _some_ alternative

Comment: @AMtwo hello! What about Aaron? In all recent cases he was the one to save the day. Well, the dump. :D

Comment: Aaron just took the metaphorical slaps for me, by handling the public comms. It was the other redundant DBRE who got the process running smoothly, and me pointing and crying when I had to manually upload files after it got hung.

Comment: An uncharitable observer might conclude the data contradicts the company's narrative. I'm not feeling particular charitable right now.

Comment: Interestingly, the public availability of the data was a main reason I choose to contribute to stack exchange in the first place. If that's not just a delay, I might request deletion of all my contributions.

Comment: @miku You don't have an option to delete your contributions, you've already licensed them out (and the terms don't give you any option for revocation). Future contributions you can decide on, though.

Comment: @miku You cannot do that. Your contributions aren't yours anymore. When you posted, you basically gave the content to the company (and everyone) and this is not retractable. You have a right to be dissociated from the content though. And of course you can stop contributing in the future.

Comment: @miku The closest you can come is a [GDPR Data Deletion Request](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/gdpr/request). Some more info & discussion [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376712/314146)

Comment: Jody has responded in an answer below. I've updated the status to planned.

Comment: Can we get the official answer accepted, please?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 -- The official answer is less complete than the most upvoted answer. I know "official company answers" are usually considered the "most correct" but in this case, I think AMtwo wrote the more informative answer. So I've accepted his.

Comment: @DataDude Acceptance, here, would be for visibility. It's important for people to be able to see the official answer. (Answer quality is what votes are for.)

Comment: I've been using SE for more than a decade and this is the first I've heard about a data dump. Can you explain to me like I'm five what this is for and why normal users should care that your favourite toy just got taken away

Comment: @Richard https://web.archive.org/web/20230203170609/https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/04/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/. [Quoting Journeyman Geek](/q/389558/997587), "_our insurance policy should the company go evil_". That plus the CC-BY-SA license

Comment: @Rosie what does the status planned mean here though? That the data dumps would be released in some form, or SE is digging in its heels and there will be serious restrictions to access by the community that has contributed all the content that's actually in the dump?

Comment: @Starball - That link doesn't help in the slightest. It's just more people saying how fab it is, without any examples of why it's fab and what they're using it for.

Comment: @Richard https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/10/20/introducing-the-overflow-offline-project/ is one example

Comment: As much as such things exist and can be dated, Jun 9, 2023 was the end of Web 2.0 as we know it with the Reddit CEO's AMA and this post. It's a pity. It was a good run, I guess.

Comment: @Richard "_It's just more people saying how fab it is, without any examples of why it's fab and what they're using it for_"... there's so much. Basically anything you could use [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) for. Doing data analysis and research (and all the wide, various applications of that- Ex. [disproving false claims about the platform from on high](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389960/997587)). SEDE has query timeouts. A data dump does not.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek it's a first aid plaster to stop the bleeding. Nothing more. (aka give those who want to believe it that SE actually plan to do anything. I don't buy it.)

Comment: @starball - Sorry, but all. I'm seeing is fringe cases and obscure apps that benefit a tiny number of people.

Comment: @Richard well, at this point, if you're not convinced, it's in the eye of the beholder. https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries

Comment: @starball - So use that

Comment: @Richard Again, SEDE has query timeouts. A data dump does not. And SEDE is hosted by Stack Exchange and Stack Exchange can take that down whenever they want. At this point, I wouldn't even be surprised if they did. But once you've downloaded a data dump, they can't take that away from you (what would they do? knock on your door?). [Subscriber content is CC-BY-SA](/legal/terms-of-service).

Comment: @chx - Good comment. Yes, the end of Web 2.0. And if I might make a prediction, Google too will stop "providing" so much of their service for "free". (I won't be surprised if they stop letting people use their websearch engine except through an app.) Yes I know most of it is advertising, but still. Web 2.0 was akin to a bait and switch operation.

Comment: The strikers' organisation needs to download the March dump and fast, if they haven't already done so.

Comment: @starball the data dump itself is also licensed under CC BY-SA, in addition to the user content under that license.

Comment: @starball, the [Site's TOS](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service) states: "From time to time, Stack Overflow may make available compilations of all the Subscriber Content on the public Network (the “Creative Commons Data Dump”). The Creative Commons Data Dump is licensed under the CC BY-SA license. By downloading the Creative Commons Data Dump, you agree to be bound by the terms of that license."   So the Data Dump's enrichment (internal IDs, enums, etc) is also covered under CC BY-SA, in addition to the subscriber content.

Comment: Alternatively, you could rephrase this to be the actual statement, with additional info and prompt for questions, Q&A style. Thomas Owens and kaya3 had on-point concerns that probably could be expanded here, rather than a self-answer that is a mirror of another question.

Comment: Should this be changed to status-completed

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog It’s good to see that was already done.

Comment: I suppose but its sure not planned anymore @AMtwo

Comment: I don't understand the strategy of opening up or not opening up of new questions by the company. Sometimes they hijack their old questions and update them with new information, now they open up a new question with the same content as an old question. They should know how this Q&A system is supposed to work.

Comment: Regarding that part "Will the company continue to provide them going forward?" of the question, the only possible answer is that nobody knows. This part of the question is as useful as asking "Will AI take over the world?"

Comment: @wimi related: [Show MSE posts authored by staff members on the homepage regardless of the vote count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332474/997587)

Comment: @wimi "I would never have seen the announcement there." Why not? Many others seem to see it there and it would have been accepted. The question was "Where are the June data dumps?" and the accepted answer would say "Here they are?". Better than having two questions about it in order to see the accepted answer faster. How will anyone even later find out what really happened? We don't pin accepted answers anymore. This is maybe a case where one sees the drawbacks of this.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution "How will anyone even later find out what really happened"... what if that was exactly the thing to prevent?

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution now you got your way: the answer on the other post has been deleted and the accepted answer here says "the data dump is disabled", which is not true. The [strike update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390106/643262) also says nothing about the reenablement. I still think this is malicious misleading of the users, but whatever, it seems that SE is fine with it.

Comment: @wimi Of course the right answer should be accepted. I will remind the OP. And maybe I should also edit the official posts to clearly mark them as official. I think the number of votes and comments show that the official answers aren't forgotten. Believe me, a single question is better if done right.

Comment: @DataDude Please change the acceptance mark to the post by Philippe. It's also the newest official post about the topic.

Comment: @ShadowWizardStrikesBack there were some bumps in the road, but as mentioned, there was a lot of good work done that made the process much more observable and resilient recently.

Comment: ^ Concur - I wouldn't have wanted to babysit this process without some of the great enhancements @PatrickHurst and Andy have made, especially earlier this year.

Comment: @AaronBertrand good to see you're still around. But I'm really concerned, both about the data dumps (management can snipe finger and shut them down again any moment), and SE in general, as it's sinking now into the AI depths.

Answer (score 275, accepted):

##### Update 2023-06-18

[The Data Dump has been re-enabled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390200/314146). The latest data dump is available on [The Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange). It was uploaded at 2023-06-14, and contains data up to 2023-06-03.

Additionally, [a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389922/june-2023-data-dump-is-missing#comment1302913_390200) written by Stack Overflow founder [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) under the [official response](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390200/314146) reads (emphasis his):

> I have confirmation via email from Prashanth that this is, indeed, *the new official policy*. I'm glad to see it. Creative Commons is part of our contract with the community, and it should never be broken -- however, CC does need to address the AI issue in an updated license, in my personal opinion.
>  -- Jeff Atwood

---

##### Original Answer

> ***DISCLAIMER:** I was recently impacted by [the Company's layoff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389060). I am going to carefully respond in a way that ensures I don't reveal anything the Company may feel is confidential--particularly with regard to strategy, or future plans. Any knowledge I have on strategy or future plans is both dated and confidential, and thus it would be irresponsible for me to say more. As a result, this answer may feel incomplete. I suspect that the CM team is rather busy this week with other topics. I'm offering what I can to uphold the Company's values of Transparency & being Community-centric.*

### The upload to the Internet Archive has been disabled.

The job that uploads the data dump to Archive.org was disabled on 28 March, and marked to not be re-enabled without approval of senior leadership. Had it run as scheduled, it would have completed on the first Monday after the first Sunday in June.

I mention the timing, as this change long pre-dated the current moderator strike and related policy changes. Some comments have suggested otherwise, so I thought it an important detail.

### Is it going to stay that way?

The following is an excerpt from [a different answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390040/314146) provided by [Jody Bailey, CTO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1196463/jody-bailey) of Stack Overflow:

> We are looking for ways to gate access to the Dump, APIs, and SEDE, that will allow individuals access to the data while preventing misuse by organizations looking to profit from the work of our community. We are working to design and implement appropriate safeguards and still sorting out the details and timelines. We will provide regular updates on our progress to this group.

### How can I access that data?

[Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com) (aka SEDE) contains a subset of all data for all sites, with PII removed. The same data available in the data dump is also available on SEDE.

SEDE is updated via a weekly full refresh (every weekend). The Data Dump that is uploaded to Archive.org is a dump of the SEDE databases. The weekly SEDE refresh runs, then the data is dumped to XML & 7zipped, then the 7z files are uploaded to the Archive.

SEDE can't address all the use cases of the Data Dump, nor vice versa. However, there is overlap, and the data is at least queryable.

Comment: Well that sucks...

Comment: I’m sad to see that this has happened. Thank you for providing an answer.

Comment: The data dump is also part of the commitment the company has had with the community for years. I would guess this is part of their master plan to sell data but some heads up would have been nice.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Asking for forgiveness is easier than asking for permission amirite?

Comment: @amtwo thanks for the update, I guess. "this answer may feel incomplete" --yes, it does feel incomplete. Hopefully someone at Stack can fill in the gaps. If they don't, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: I see next step is going full Reddit and asking payment for API usage...

Comment: @DataDude not really no

Comment: If they're doing this because they plan to sell access to the data, that would make some business sense except that people who are using this data to, say, train AI models, currently [believe that doing so is fair-use](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/388589/401068), and they can do so by crawling the data publicly available. Anyone with a financial interest big enough to spend money on the data is going to be just as capable of obtaining the data without the dump, so this only affects people like academic researchers.

Comment: I would never have thought I'd see the day, but this is the end for me on SO. The unwritten contract between me and this platform was that the knowledge remains freely accessible and archiveable while I contribute. Since this didn't happen anymore, well after 12 years of membership, that's it. I'll leave and contribute elsewhere. Sorry, but this is a point where no compromise is possible.

Comment: @trilarion Unwritten contracts are worth the paper they're written on...

Comment: @BartSilverstrim You're right but there wasn't really any better place and I somehow hoped that they would continue doing what they did for many, many years. But it turns out they are evil after all, so I will go. No, I will run. As fast as I can. Anywhere. Just away from here.

Comment: @AMtwo I admire your commitment to the community even after the company has thrown you under the bus.

Comment: The Data Dump was literally one of the safeguards in case the company became evil! And I do mean literally - Jeff or Joel said that, in the early days of Stack Overflow.

Comment: maybe if it was a nonprofit, none of this would have happened by now :/ this is sad times

Comment: @trilarion I'm not blaming you for believing their "core values" or other such corp-speak. How long did it take for Google to show their "do no evil" mantra was more tell than show? If https://codidact.com could get more audience, I think they have a better foundation to help prevent this kind of future behavior, but without the community to answer questions, it would be a tough sell. Too bad Google couldn't offer it in their preferred search results!

Comment: This is deeply concerning. If the next step is making all API access paid, I'm going to resign. Numerous community-driven tools, including in moderation, rely heavily on on the API to function. Forcing all those projects or even just individuals making QOL tools to pay for something that benefits the platform is outright despicable and self-destructive, and is not the SO I signed up for

Comment: Just sorta stating the obvious here, but the timing of this is _unbelievably_ terrible; I actually can't fathom a worse time for this call to be made than in light of this week.

Comment: @zcoop98 Well, the call was made 3 months ago and hidden from the community. It's just exploding today.

Comment: So the company unilaterally changed the policy and didn't even tell us about it? Who could have seen this coming?

Comment: @kaya3 They did not announce it here, but did announce it to the press, and it was discussed here. https://www.wired.com/story/stack-overflow-will-charge-ai-giants-for-training-data/ https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388551/is-se-going-to-be-selling-our-content-for-ai-model-training-and-what-exactly/ Not the end of the dumps, mind you, but the plans to charge for API access.

Comment: Here is where it was announced 14 years ago: https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/04/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/ RIP SE

Comment: That article is very odd @BryanKrauseisonstrike; `plans to begin charging large AI developers for access to the 50 million questions and answers on its service, CEO Chandrasekar says`, but also `Users own the content they post; when AI companies sell their models they are unable to attribute each and every one of the community members whose questions and answers were used to train the model, thereby breaching the Creative Commons license, Chandrasekar says.` So, ehm, will SO charging monies fix those license issues (potential issues, as it's legally unclear now AFAIK)? Of course it won't.

Comment: I don't even have a problem with the "fair use" usage for AI training models personally, and I also don't even have a problem with Stack Overflow charging for it as long as it doesn't hurt the community, but I do have a lot more problems with this kind of dishonest spin. That's very hard to trust.

Comment: @MartinTournoij I agree, it makes absolutely no sense. It appears the CEO is entirely clueless on all of this. And it's not like including a bunch of additional AI answers in the data they want to sell will make it more worth buying.

Comment: @BryanKrauseisonstrike I was also quite puzzled by the contradiction between charging AI companies for data, and allowing AI answers on the network; but this is now explained by the internal analysis which “shows” that almost no AI answers are being posted any more. I seriously doubt the AI companies will fall for this claim; but if so, they are likely to sue after they find out the truth.

Comment: @Restore You're absolutely right! I phrased that badly, it wasn't decided today; the fact that it came to pass this week of all weeks is what's unbelievable to me. The punches just keep coming...

Comment: https://creativecommons.org/2023/02/17/fair-use-training-generative-ai/

Comment: > Transparency & being Community-centric > Disabled a transparency feature without telling the community > Took multiple days to respond to questions about it > Responded by saying it's *their* data to profit off of, not others' -- Please, they've laid you off; you don't have to pretend those are actually SO values anymore.

Comment: @DimeCadmium -- regardless of my employment status, I personally value transparency and supporting the communities I'm a part of. Those are stated values of the company and part of why I started working there. And they are still things that I value highly. I don't see it as lip service to the company at all--if anything, it's a reminder to *everyone involved* about the origins of this site. No tea, no shade, just a reminder to everyone to take a breath and look up.

Comment: For the record, I honestly and strongly believe that unless this post, we wouldn't have a new data dump, now or ever. They could use some excuse which people from the outside could never verify.

Answer (score 153):

Few things have made me more livid than what we've just learned through the [answer given by AMtwo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390023/249658).

**The data dump is one of the main reasons why I'm still participating to this day and has been part of the core values of this community. Please restore it, or consult with us to establish some equivalent way to protect and export our contributions as a whole.**

I would like to bring the following pieces of history to the foreground. This is an excerpt of Joel Spolsky speaking on the [Stack Overflow podcast #84](https://dev.to/stackpodcast/podcast-84)

> Oh, expropriation of community content that... We created Stack
> Overflow to be against it. If there's anything that's more in the DNA
> of Stack Overflow than that, I don't know what it is. That's one of
> our most core things. You can see this all over the place in the
> design of Stack Overflow.
>
> First of all, from day one, we use the CC-wiki license. And it's
> basically a license, it says that we don't own the content that's on
> there, which is why we make those database dumps that are available.
>
> Because we wanted to make sure that if no matter what happens,
> literally no matter who we sell to, or raise money from, or turn the
> site over to, and even if they take Stack Overflow, and make it an
> evil site where you have to pay to look at things and there's pop-up
> ads and pop-under ads, and you know, dancing chariots of fire that
> cross the screen and punch the monkey, and, man, I can take so many
> evil things anyway. And it just becomes a big gigantic spam site.
>
> Doesn't matter because just take the latest CC-wiki download that we
> provided and go start your own site saying, you know what, this is
> gonna be the clean version. And I think a lot of people will follow
> you. We very, very deliberately built Stack Overflow in a way that there
> wouldn't be any chance of locking and we're pretty much doing the same
> thing with Stack Exchange.

Also, on the [blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/04/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/), written by Jeff Atwood in 2009:

> The community has selflessly provided all this content in the spirit
> of sharing and helping each other. In that very same spirit, we are
> happy to return the favor by providing a database dump of public data.

Comment: yes, that was Joel. [In the meantime, the current management...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388551/is-se-going-to-be-selling-our-content-for-ai-model-training-and-what-exactly) Have my vote, it is always useful having people pointing out how the current direction the company is going is against anything the network was meant to stand for in the past.

Comment: So who's spinning up the clone with the latest dump? Do we need to get a kickstarter going or something?

Answer (score 126):

**Friday evening**

That's it, and the dump is uploaded.  Many thanks to the stackers involved, especially Aaron Bertrand, who babysat the thing for days.

**Update as of Friday morning**  (2023-06-16 12:29:39Z)

We're at 40%, average upload speed is 0.25 Mbps :(

This is not likely to complete today.

**Update as of Thursday evening** (2023-06-16 00:52:06Z)

We're pleased to say that all but one of the files are completed, ahead of the promised schedule.  However, the remaining one file (32 gigs) is uploading extremely slowly due to some network slowness.  Unfortunately, I think it is likely that the remaining file will not be uploaded by end of day Friday as we initially hoped. We have folks who are continuing to nursemaid this incredibly slow upload along, but it is very clear that our initial plan is at risk at this point. We will get it up as soon as we can.

(We were up to over 50%, but unfortunately the job was in our NY data center, which experienced  a blip today and the job was wiped out in the process.  It has been restarted, but at 0.50 Mbps, it's slow going.  I wish I could project a completion date at this point, but I hesitate to do so because I don't want to miss another stated target.)

I would also like to apologize to the community here for the lack of clarity in my initial announcement here.  Although several people proofed it, we missed the lack of the word "permanently" in it, which caused confusion and frustration.  That was not my intent, obviously.  I thank those who counseled patience and calm while we resolved the situation, and I thank Catija for actually managing that resolution.  In short, we tried, but our editing of my initial draft was insufficient, and I own that.  It was my writing, and it was not clear.  I'll try to be sure that doesn't happen again.

**Update as of Wednesday evening** (2023-06-15 02:48:09Z):

By way of status, we began uploading the dumps yesterday.  For some reason, the Internet Archive is internet throttled right now (seriously so, we're getting around 0.25 Mbps) so it's taking MUCH longer than anticipated. Long enough that I seriously suggested writing to disk and FedEx.

However, I still anticipate that we will meet the promised delivery of end of day Friday.

---

*Posted Tuesday 2023-06-13 22:32:13Z*:

Much has been written lately of the company’s decision to pause the distribution of the anonymized data dump that has historically been posted.

Our intention was never to stop posting the data dump permanently, only to pause it while we begin to collect more information on how it was being used and by whom - especially in light of the rise of large language models (LLMs) and questions around how generative AI models are handling attribution. However, it’s clear that many individual users (academics, researchers, etc) have an immediate need to access updated versions of the dumps. So we are re-enabling the automatic data dumps (and uploading the one that’s about a week overdue). We believe that this can happen by end of the day Friday. We will continue to work toward the creation of certain guardrails (for large AI/LLM companies) for both the dumps and the API, but again - we have no intention of restricting/charging community members or other responsible users of the dumps or the API from accessing them.

As part of this project, API users should be on the lookout for a very brief survey that will be coming out (it will be announced here and on [stackapps.com](https://stackapps.com/)) that asks about the features that you most use/would like to see in the API or data dumps moving forward so that we can plan for those, as well as collect general input.

In the meantime, the data dumps will be re-enabled by end of day Friday. We will communicate here when that has been completed or if there are any delays.  We will also post here prior to making any future changes to the dumps or distribution of the dumps.

Comment: *"only to begin to collect more information on how it was being used and by whom"* ─ how does pausing the dump help you collect this information? If anything, it prevents you from collecting information on who downloads it. If people can download it, that is an opportunity to find out who those people are.

Comment: Two questions. (1) Why do you believe that you should or must "continue to work toward the creation of certain guardrails" for the data dumps and why must these guardrails be in place specifically for AI/LLM companies? (2) Will the survey be available for people who want to use the API or data dumps but don't have the features they need today?

Comment: @kaya3-supportthestrike To be fair, the dump is mostly distributed through Internet Archive & torrents; it's near-impossible to know who is downloading it directly.

Comment: @Undo Sure, but if they want to e.g. do a voluntary survey of people who are downloading it (as mentioned in this answer), the dump must exist in order for there to be any survey respondents. And we know from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390023/1135948) that the decision to disable the data dumps was made in March, so if the intention was always only to start collecting this survey data, it doesn't make sense that the June dump was delayed, unless it took months to write the survey.  And if this was the plan all along, it's strange that the other answer makes no mention of it.

Comment: A thought: use the textual equivalent of [trap streets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trap_street) in the dumps of future times (if you can figure out how). These may provide a key to identification of unauthorised AIs

Comment: The claim that the plan all along was just to collect data on who is using the dump for what purposes, directly contradicts [this other answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390040/1135948) from an SE staff member who says the dumps were stopped in order to prevent LLM developers from using the data.

Comment: Can you shed any light on why such a rash move was made in the first place without any consideration of the community? It would've saved a lot of trouble in the first place. '*we have no intention of restricting/charging community members or other responsible users of the dumps or the API from accessing them.*' - What is your definition of *responsible users*?

Comment: Also, if this is your response, why did it take so long? The original question on data dumps was posted on 7th, the reply from Jody on 9th, and your response today (14th). Again, the point here is that it would've saved a lot backlash.

Comment: I have confirmation via email from Prashanth that this is, indeed, **the new official policy**. I'm glad to see it. Creative Commons is part of our contract with the community, and it should never be broken -- however, CC *does* need to address the AI issue in an updated license, in my personal opinion. @wizzwizz4 I also edited the other post to cross link to this one.

Comment: @JeffAtwood Isn't this solved in a trivial but legal manner? A LLM providing derivative work from SE's data corpus, by definition, needs to attribute (this is a mandatory requirement in the license). As much as I hate to put it this way, CC-BY-SA already covers this in terms of enforcement conditions, and it would be significantly better to work on this rather than attempting to gate the content (trivially beaten by scraping, BTW).

Comment: There is an ongoing [court case](https://www.reuters.com/legal/ai-companies-ask-us-court-dismiss-artists-copyright-lawsuit-2023-04-19/) about this exact topic applied to art. Unlike the Copilot one, this one is remixed works rather than copied works.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld completely agree, AIs should ABSOLUTELY label and attribute the contents, just like any food item you purchase at a store has a list of ingredients on it, as well as caloric info. At minimum you have a right to know what exactly is in that jambalaya you just ate. Heck, you might want to push content improvements / error corrections upstream, and you can't even do that when you don't know where the information came from! Just the other day ChatGPT told me that ZZ Top had no song titled "I Need You Tonight". Well, uh.. https://music.youtube.com/watch?v=PTiwF0z5Auc

Comment: @SébastienRenauld AI folks have argued using data for training is Fair Use, and if that's true then none of the license terms apply to them, because they're using an exception to the entire copyright concept.

Comment: "it’s clear that many individual users (academics, researchers, etc) have an immediate need to access updated versions of the dumps" Then why did you switch the data dumps off only to switch them now on again? Either you didn't know that or this message here isn't completely honest. Neither sounds particularly inspiring to me. As a general rule I'd say that whenever you even only think about turning the data dumps off you already doing something wrong. It's a bit difficult to believe they were only paused. Sorry, but my trust is very low. Too many bad actions lately.

Comment: Turning the dumps back on was the right thing to do. +1 for that. But at the same time this post is *still* gaslighting us as to what happened and why (-1 for that) and also totally wishy-washy on what you comit to doing (-1). You've already illegially relicenced my contributions once and maintained radio silence about it, now you are hinting at a plan to do it again.

Comment: @JeffAtwood "AIs should ABSOLUTELY label and attribute the contents" true but it's not easy to do. [How can a language model keep track of the provenance of the main knowledge/sources used to generate a given output?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/38372/4)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt You asked the question law about it and even lawyers don't know yet. When the CC license was invented they didn't think about AI enough. AI is borderline (un)fair use because it just uses a tiny bit of every input for a given output (except sometimes it uses more).

Comment: So. The data dump releases were stopped without any form of announcement and ***as usual*** it took someone to notice before the company admitted it was something already planned for at least a month. You say that it was "to get stats about who uses it" while a different post claims that you were past that phase and trying to gate the access to the data. After a while coincidentally when user  started to plan about how to produce the data themselves the decision is put on stop for a while and you post this answer, once again denying the users to reply and forcing them to use comments [cont...]

Comment: [cont...] comments that conveniently are often cleaned up. Even the announcement is *again* posted in the "fake question" format as if it was a FAQ. And all of this looks like throwing a bone so that the mods on strike feel like they have achieved something and may be easier herd to an agreement that is favorable to the company... Sorry, I can't help but be suspicious at these reiterated changes of direction and information artificial scarcity

Comment: *Our intention was never to stop posting the data dump, only to begin to collect more information on how it was being used and by whom* => you do realize that this is literally impossible to do as long as SE remains under CC-BY-SA? Individual users could hypothetically sue the AI companies for breaching the license but SE cannot gatekeep the content or demand that users of the content explains themselves. That's the whole point of Creative Commons.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1711/discussion-on-answer-by-philippe-june-2023-data-dump-is-missing); to preserve them** - two answers were merged leaving many semi-duplicate comments. So that some could be cleared, I've created a chat room that shows all of the comments as of this point.

Comment: Hey all - we understand the confusion about how this answer was conveyed. I've worked with Philippe to identify ways we can address your feedback and, as such, I've merged the two questions and moved the comments from one to the other so that they're all in one place. Additionally, I've clarified the statement so that it conveys what we intended as we understand that this was being interpreted as a different story from what Jody shared previously. Apologies for any confusion.

Comment: @Catija the biggest problem is still trying to figure out what the "truth" actually is. The original statement by the CTO, the original - misleading to put it nicely - statement by Philippe - or your revised one once you saw the backlash from the statement itself. '*that this was being interpreted as a different story from what Jody shared previously.*' - it literally was a different story. Jody mentioned the decision to pause/stop the dumps was intentional to prevent "abuse", the original statement said that the intention wasn't to pause. There is/was no misinterpretation.

Comment: @Script47 For communication to be that precise you need to have dozens of people drafting statements together to rule out every possible misinterpretation and even then you're likely to get it wrong some of the time. It's often difficult when you know what the actual situation is to write perfectly unambiguously. That's one of the reasons we have an edit feature here. I think Catija's edits reconcile the two statements quite clearly after the discrepancy was pointed out. I don't think the stories were actually that different. I still think it was silly because AI isn't using the data dump.

Comment: If we want the company to communicate with us, I think it's better to expect back-and-forth communication and clarification as appropriate, rather than to demand that each message is conveyed perfectly at the first release. It's a barrier to actually communicating if they need to spend hours on each and every draft message. I think about how much iteration went into drafting the strike letter: that's okay for a one-off thing, but if every message took that much effort, the will to communicate is going to evaporate pretty quickly.

Comment: @BryanKrauseisonstrike are you kidding? How difficult is it to say *this is why we disabled the dump, this is what we were thinking, clearly it's not what the community wanted so here's what we're thinking now...*. Instead the CTO came out saying we intentionally stopped it for X and then another statement saying that it wasn't our intention to stop the dump, and then claiming that people are misinterpreting the statement.

Comment: @BryanKrauseisonstrike you can choose to continue playing defense for SO and talk about they need X, Y, or Z, but SO isn't the tiny company they used to me and ironically, they did communication better when they were smaller and had less resources. '*but if every message took that much effort, the will to communicate is going to evaporate pretty quickly*' - The will has disappeared already. Not because of the community but because they saw the $$$ in catering another audience or by moving away from the original ethos. I can't believe people are *still* trying to make excuses for them.

Comment: @BryanKrauseisonstrike they had from 7th June to release an unambiguous statement and they still managed to flop that by trying to gaslight the situation. There comes a point where you simply have to call it as it is, incompetence/maliciousness. Maybe if they actually let CMs do their jobs, not silence then, or kept the talent they had it wouldn't be so difficult. We set the bar for contributors/power users/mods and other people so high, why drop it for the company?

Comment: @Script47 I think you're overemphasizing certain phrasings to *make* them unclear in your head rather than trying to reconcile. I think a better communication approach when you get conflicting information is to point out the potential conflict and ask for clarification; that has now happened, so, what's the problem? I am not playing defense for SO. I am very strongly urging them to make changes I feel are necessary to keep the sites I like to use operational.

Comment: @BryanKrauseisonstrike ah yes, I point something factual out and it's *unclear in my head*. The problem you ask about is simple, words have meanings, Catija wrote: '*interpreted as a different story from what Jody shared previously*', it wasn't being interpreted differently, it literally was different. Jody suggested they stopped the dumps to prevent "abuse" the original statement suggested that they only meant to collect information. That is literally different. If you don't want me to criticise then just say that but there is a problem, that is, if you grant that words have meanings.

Comment: @Script47 "Our intention was never to stop posting the data dump" is ambiguous, not different; the word stop does not indicate whether it is permanent or temporary. Jody used the word in the temporary sense, Philippe used it in a permanent sense. In Jody's post, the meaning is clarified by the word "until" later in the sentence. Now, Catija edited Philippe's post to make clear he meant the permanent sense. Now there is no ambiguity in either use of the word. However, if you assumed the statements were consistent to begin with, that interpretation was also available with the words used here.

Comment: @BryanKrauseisonstrike Jody said: '*[...] While working on this strategy, we decided to stop the dump until we could put guardrails in place.*' which is different from Philippe's statement: '*Our intention was never to stop posting the data dump, only to begin to collect more information on how it was being used and by whom*'. These are two different things, not a misinterpretation as Catija said. That's all my point is. I'm *really* not sure what you're arguing for/against here.

Comment: @Script47 Philippe's statement is that the purpose of the pause was to collect information and indicated the overall effort is related to AI training data and the possibility of guardrails for large scale use of the data. Jody's statement is also that the purpose of the pause is to put up guardrails. I don't see conflict here, just emphasis on different parts of a plan that, thankfully, was reconsidered after information was gathered, including the importance of the dumps to people other than those they want to block.

Comment: I would have preferred Philippe's statement to acknowledge that this unannounced pause caused a lot of valid angst in the community and include an apology for this impact, and I would have preferred that it recognize explicitly the previous commitments made by the company to users regarding the release of data, but I do not think the message conflicts with the CTO, particularly after the clarifying edits.

Comment: @BryanKrauseisonstrike look, Brian, I think no one is trying to play a syntactic  meaning game here - thing like "it was never promised that the company would no longer slander users group, just individual" is a level of technicality that is better left to Tolkien elves. Problem is that the way this came out is confusing at best (cont)

Comment: The company stopped the dump without any warning, a sign that many already interpreted as malice. Then an ex-employee posted an internal discussion that talked about "gating access to the dump" to companies - something that matched the other discovery of an article talking about intentions of "monetizing the data dumps" (remember the license). Then caught red-handed we got a first explanation they "stopped the dump while putting guardrails". Later there was a change - "we stopped while we collected data about its use". The narrative keeps changing with each new message...

Comment: And all of this happens during a strike, without no explanation about WHY this was keep hidden until someone noticed, why online news sites have access to more information than the site users, how they plan to put guardrails in place without changing how the content is distributed (even if they required an account, anyone could make one. Or anyone with access could just mirror the dumps on their blog).. all while looking as a suspiciously convenient way to show that the company did its part in "reaching out to the striking mods". Really, I can see why users are mad.

Comment: @JeffAtwood I completely agree that CC should address LLM usage. However, ChatGPT did not use a data dump to train, but https://commoncrawl.org/, so that's the place to start to enforce any possible CC changes, not the dump. Also, I think it's intrinsic to CC that we allow any usage that respects attribution, not merely _some_ usage that we prefer at the moment.

Comment: @SPArcheon Let's say you have an outdoor party scheduled. You show up, no tables are set up outside, and event staff tell you "We're setting up inside because of the thunderstorms coming". You leave to take care of some things, they call you a couple hours later and say "Hey, we looked at the forecast, it changed, so we're setting up outside again". The argument I have a problem with is the one that would see this reversion as a breach, because although the staff explained "we're moving inside because of weather", they never mentioned part of the plan was to keep checking the weather.

Comment: @SPArcheon I think there's a very valid complaint that they should have never done this without prior announcement to the community. But, I do not think that the subsequent messaging is inconsistent, and I think it's counterproductive to focus on discrepancies between Jody and Philippe's posts because *I don't think those discrepancies are actually important*. Better to focus on the things that are actual problems, like the initial lack of communication. If everything is attacked equally, it just becomes a muddy mess.

Comment: To put it bluntly - I think people are going to understand technical difficulties slowing things down over... "We turned it off and never told anyone". And the entire network going down is a very acceptable reason for things being delayed.

Comment: As the one nursing the process, I can confirm that the final file from the June dump has been fully uploaded, has gone through the usual processing by archive.org, and is now available for consumption. It actually finished at 22:42 UTC so, if we want to be technical, it was still delivered by end of day Friday. :-)

Comment: So, after being caught red handed, you mitigated the instant danger, without a single apology of course, and didn't mention what will happen next time, i.e. in three months. Will you prevent access again, without telling anyone? Will you wait, again, for someone to notice, report, and then if one of the staff or former staff will confirm it was done in purpose bring it back? Sadly, I'm sure the answer is a big YES. So I'm sorry, but not sorry, but I don't buy this move.

Comment: This is very thinly veiled spin on top of blatant untruths. You're trying to tell a huge room full of engineers that you turned a service off *to collect data*?

Answer (score 88):

> We are looking for ways to gate access to the Dump, APIs, and SEDE, that will allow individuals access to the data while preventing misuse by organizations looking to profit from the work of our community.

That ship has *sailed*. OpenAI's currently publicly available models (at time of writing) famously have a knowledge cut-off date of 2021, and few people care. Stack Exchange data is gathered, and fed into these models, via [the Common Crawl project](https://commoncrawl.org/). Nobody is using Stack Exchange Data Dumps to train AI models.

Even if you were willing to violate the CC BY-SA licenses (of various versions) under which we contributed all that we have contributed, and release the data dumps under some restrictive license, *it would achieve nothing*, because these companies are *already* not respecting the restrictions of the licenses.

Rightly or wrongly (imo, wrongly), *All Rights Reserved* is being interpreted as legal permission to perform bulk statistical analyses that launder away any hope of attribution, then justify the actions by the fact that attribution becomes technically impossible. Our CC BY-SA license doesn't stand a chance. If Prosus wants a return on its investment in Stack Overflow, it should consider putting its weight behind getting the "SA" part of the license enforced against the likes of OpenAI. (I'd happily waive 20% of my part of the settlement from [a collective-action lawsuit](https://githubcopilotlitigation.com/case-updates.html), if you want to profit more directly, and I'm happy to negotiate something higher.)

What you're doing now is just… destroying the network. For no good reason. I've *stopped recommending people to Stack Overflow* – when normally I would be teaching entire classes full of students how to use it. I am now [*actively avoiding contributing Q&A*](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1202/278), which is a shame, because I've got 7 or 8 Q&A pairs tucked away in my drafts folder, meant for Stack Overflow, that I may never have the motivation to polish up now.

What you hope to achieve here is unachievable. Ask your lawyer. Heck, ask on [Law Stack Exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/). What you're doing is *not helping*, and you do not know that you do not know that.

---

Side note: SEDE is already gated behind a Google ReCAPTCHA for not-logged-in users. That's to prevent people taking down your servers with a trillion high-intensity unauthenticated requests, but it serves this purpose quite competently, too. (If you want to make it slightly stricter, gate un-ReCAPTCHA'd SEDE behind the 15-reputation barrier used for upvoting: we have solid empirical evidence that that's high enough to make abuse detectable and manageable.)

Comment: @Andreasdetestscensorship Codidact's website is hard for me to use – harder than modern Stack Exchange, would you believe? But I suppose I could donate improvements and bug fixes to it.

Comment: Yes, I looked into Codidact in 2020, and wanted to switch, but the UI was painful. It still is. That can be changed, though. I really like the SE UI, but copying that, and then improving it, likely isn’t legal.

Comment: @Andreas detests censorship: Yes, it was also too buggy (server errors) the last time I looked. But perhaps it is time for another look. It is the most obvious destination for Stack Exchange refugees.

Comment: Re "violate the CC BY-SA licenses", I suppose you mean "in spirit", but I'll note that *sui generis* database rights are not necessarily eliminated, especially for posts until 2018 with the older licenses.

Comment: I have been switching to Codidact. At the current community size, the Meta there puts you pretty much directly in contact with the actual developers. If you see opportunities to improve the UI, please speak up!

Answer (score 63):

To highlight the significance that the data dump may have held for me and others:

I signed up to Stack Overflow in order to contribute to a free library of knowledge for everyone, knowing that the content license meant that I give my knowledge to everyone in the world (even AI companies if they can abide by the license but just to everyone, the license doesn't differentiate uses, it's all the same to it). I liked that a lot and wanted that. Specifically, I never wanted to lock my knowledge in only one location. That's why I saw the quarterly data dumps not only as an addon but as an essential core part of this service. And this understanding worked for many years.

But now the company is not the same anymore than it used to be (with Jeff Atwood at the helm) and they cancelled the insurance (the data dumps) in order to stop some competition.

That doesn't help me. I want that everyone can use my knowledge equally, only limited by the license requirements (attribution, whatever that means nowadays). While legally nothing has changed (although the company was also really bad in this regard in the past), practically the data dumps were the only independent and accessible storage of the knowledge. I wanted the company to compete on a technological level with better features, not by locking in the content more.

Without the data dumps I trust the company exactly as much as zero. There is no compromise possible for me. I cannot continue under these circumstances.

And I hope I never have to read any of these blog posts about community at the center ever again.

Comment: Maybe the blog title was trying to say that the community was being used *as the pavement* for the road to AI? It was kind of ambiguously worded...

Comment: They may have an "alternative" definition of "community": <Censored> labour.

Comment: "community at the center" - sure, center of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ET9U8.png). They throw darts on us, and we just started to realize it now. :/

Answer (score 46):

The resumption of these dumps is very welcome, and I'm glad the company has decided to listen to the community on this issue.

That said, there's something in [Phillipe's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390200/1135948) which doesn't sound right to me:

> Our intention was never to stop posting the data dump, only to begin to collect more information on how it was being used and by whom

Both parts of this statement apparently contradict other statements by SE, Inc. staff (former and current).

According to [AMtwo's answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390023/1135948), *"The job that uploads the data dump to Archive.org was disabled on 28 March, and marked to not be re-enabled without approval of senior leadership."* This is inconsistent with the claim that the intention was never to stop posting the data dump; it was stopped in March, and the stopping was clearly intentional.

Also, according to [Jody Bailey's answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390040/1135948), SE, Inc. is *"working on a strategy to protect Stack Overflow data from being misused by companies building LLMs. While working on this strategy, we decided to stop the dump until we could put guardrails in place."* This is inconsistent with the claim that the pause in availability of the dump was "only" so that SE, Inc. could begin to collect information about usage.

If it's true that the intention was only ever to begin collecting information about usage, why was this intention not mentioned earlier, and why was a *different* intention mentioned instead?

Comment: my guess is there is internal disagreement about how to handle this. Hence the mixed messaging. I have ZERO inside insight, that's just my opinion.  I am a very very VERY strong advocate of sticking to the guarantees we made with the CC license from inception, though. I think CC needs to revise / update their license to cover the AI use case, personally.

Comment: @JeffAtwood First someone has to argue successfully that using copyrighted work to train AI to generate content doesn't fall under Fair Use. I expect that to be quite expensive because all the companies using GenAI are going to be on the other side with deep pockets.

Comment: Training a large language model is a derivative work, therefore requires attribution of everyone who contributed to the training data?

Comment: @gerrit [Is it illegal for a firm to train an AI model on a CC BY-SA 4.0 corpus and make a commercial use of it without distributing the model under CC BY-SA?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/91785/31). Note that before LLMs, we had the same question for word embeddings, but few people raised the issue back then [Distributing machine learning models (e.g., word embeddings) based on non-sharable datasets](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/11183/31) and I don't recall seeing any court cases about it.

Comment: Considering that thanks to "some meddling ex employees" the cat was already out of the bag there was no need to try to keep this secret anymore. Even better, by conceding this right now they are giving the userbase the "false" idea that they "won" something, and this could make them more well disposed and yielding in whatever discussion about ending the strike is going on right now.

Comment: @JeffAtwood "I think CC needs to revise / update their license to cover the AI use case, personally." But then this newly revised CC licenses maybe wouldn't be compatible with the older CC versions anymore with difficulties for editing content. And how should that be solved practically? I cannot literally acknowledge every single place I learned something from when typing something. Should I write endless lists of footnotes with possible references for why I might say what I say?

Answer (score 45):

> Stack Overflow senior leadership is working on a strategy to <strike>protect</strike> *be able to solely monetize* Stack Overflow data <strike>from being misused</strike> by *charging* companies building LLMs *extortionate amounts of money*. While working on this strategy, we decided to stop the dump until we could put guardrails in place. *Once again ignoring the community instead of being proactive and informing them regarding this.*
>
> We are working on setting up the infrastructure to do this correctly in the age of LLMs --- where we continue to be open and share the data with our developer community but work to set up a formal framework for large AI companies that want to leverage the data.

*We're quickly scrambling because this would be an amazing opportunity for us to make some more money off your backs.*

> We are looking for ways to gate access to the Dump, APIs, and SEDE, that will allow individuals access to the data while preventing misuse by organizations looking to profit from the work of our community. We are working to design and implement appropriate safeguards and still sorting out the details and timelines.

*We're probably going to degrade the experience for people within the community who used to use these dumps because we need to somehow get companies to pay us to use this data in a more friendly way.*

As for this this line:

> We will provide regular updates on our progress to this group.

*Group?*

Do they mean *group* as in *group of users interested in the dumps*? Or, are they that detached with the community that they call these sites *groups* like you have WhatsApp *groups*?

Nevertheless, I can't believe this was actually unironically written when they didn't even bother to tell the community that this was happening.

I guess this is what comes from having employees that no longer interact with the community.

Anyone who seriously trusts SO after all they've done deserves to be fooled.

---

> "imagine if stackexchange went from free to paid..." All of the content posted by users on Stack Exchange network is licensed under CC-BY-SA. If SE ever blocks free access to the content, anyone can host it elsewhere. Pulling EE-like shenanigans is not practical in SE.
>
> [Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92683/what-experts-exchange-thinks-of-stack-overflow/95311#comment239420_95311)

> @JCL1178: I agree except the data is open source. If EE dies, the data is gone, especially if the past happens again.
>
> [Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92683/what-experts-exchange-thinks-of-stack-overflow/95311#comment239436_95311)

---

<sup>Technically speaking, this *is* an answer, you might not like it or think that it's not a great answer but it doesn't make it any less of an answer. So, if you happen to feel particularly strongly about it, feel free to downvote but I personally don't think it deserves deleting. But hey, what do I know?</sup>

¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 27):

> Our intention was never to stop posting the data dump

Okay that sounds real nice of you... But uh- why was there *zero* transparency in all of this? It was revealed by ex-staff, and *then* actual staff jumped in to stop the sh*tstorm.

> As part of this project, API users should be on the lookout for a very brief survey [...] about the features that you most use/would like to see in the API or data dumps moving forward so that we can plan for those, as well as collect general input.

Why a survey though? You have this?

- [`is:q [feature-request] [api] -[status-completed] -[status-declined] -[status-bydesign] score:1.. closed:no`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aq%20%5bfeature-request%5d%20%5bapi%5d%20-%5bstatus-completed%5d%20-%5bstatus-declined%5d%20-%5bstatus-bydesign%5d%20score%3a1..%20closed%3ano&searchOn=3)
- [`is:q [feature-request] [data-dump] -[status-completed] -[status-declined] -[status-bydesign] score:1.. closed:no`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aq%20%5bfeature-request%5d%20%5bdata-dump%5d%20-%5bstatus-completed%5d%20-%5bstatus-declined%5d%20-%5bstatus-bydesign%5d%20score%3a1..%20closed%3ano&searchOn=3)
- [`is:q [feature-request] [data-explorer] -[status-completed] -[status-declined] -[status-bydesign] score:1.. closed:no`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aq%20%5bfeature-request%5d%20%5bdata-explorer%5d%20-%5bstatus-completed%5d%20-%5bstatus-declined%5d%20-%5bstatus-bydesign%5d%20score%3a1..%20closed%3ano&searchOn=3)

Answer (score 26):

I want to re-iterate what others have said in the comments. The fact that my contributions to Stack Overflow are licensed under CC BY-SA is a significant motivating factor for why I contribute in the first place. I *want* the knowledge I share here to be accessible and freely usable by *everyone*, including LLMs, and such use is already allowed by the current license so it's unclear what "misuse" Stack Exchange Inc. is trying to prevent here.

In the past, sites have even gone so far as to mirror user content from Stack Overflow wholesale, [and that was always considered okay as long as the sites provided attribution](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253908/1157054) as required by the license and weren't doing anything illegal.

Has this changed? The wording in [Stack Exchange's official answer to this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390040/192171) has me concerned. If "organizations looking to profit from the work of our community" is now considered a problem, I suppose the next logical step is to remove the CC BY-SA license and replace it with CC BY-NC-SA, or stop releasing user contributions under an open license entirely? If that's the path things are headed down now, I will be significantly less motivated to contribute to Stack Exchange sites in the future. I want to contribute to an open repository of knowledge that anyone can use, not a proprietary database controlled entirely by Stack Exchange, Inc.

Comment: The problem is LLM's are not following the SA part. The solution is to sue them, not to make the data harder to access.

Comment: Most scraper sites don't provide proper attribution (many of which don't provide any attribution at all (pure plagiarism), to make it seem it is their own content). It could be due to ignorance, but more likely it is malicious. Or they have an "alternative" definition of plagiarism. The company [gave up ***enforcing the license*** a long time ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/413407) (reporting scrapers is busy work, fooling those who want to do the right thing).

Comment: @OrangeDog +1 you can sue LLM creators (though as per current caselaw you'll almost definitely lose) but you can't pretend like SE owns the content.

Comment: @JonathanReez indeed they don't own it, we do. But we would really like them to deal with license violators for us, right? Otherwise we all have to do it separately for our own posts, and we'll all lose, if we can even afford it in the first place. But I don't want them to pretend to do it by making stupid decisions like this.

Comment: @OrangeDog yes, they could certainly start a class action lawsuit and invite affected parties to join. But as per current caselaw they'll lose, so they'll probably have to lobby for a change in copyright law first.

Answer (score 16):

In an [answer to an identical question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390202/260073) Philippe today announced that the data dumps will be reinstated again, and the June data dump should be available soon.

> Much has been written lately of the company’s decision to pause the distribution of the anonymized data dump that has historically been posted.
>
> Our intention was never to stop posting the data dump, only to begin to collect more information on how it was being used and by whom - especially in light of the rise of LLMs and questions around how genAI models are handling attribution. However, it’s clear that many individual users (academics, researchers, etc) have an immediate need to access updated versions of the dumps. So we are re-enabling the automatic data dumps (and uploading the one that’s about a week overdue). We believe that this can happen by end of the day Friday. We will continue to work toward the creation of certain guardrails (for large AI/LLM companies) for both the dumps and the API, but again - we have no intention of restricting/charging community members or other responsible users of the dumps or the API from accessing them.
>
> As part of this project, API users should be on the lookout for a very brief survey that will be coming out (announced here and on stackapps.com) that asks about the features that you most use/would like to see in the API or data dumps moving forward so that we can plan for those, as well as collect general input.
>
> In the meantime, the data dumps will be re-enabled by end of day Friday. We will communicate here when that has been completed or if there are any delays. We will also post here prior to making any future changes to the dumps or distribution of the dumps.

My take on it: The immediate danger to data dumps not being available anymore is averted, but I find it hard to believe that it was not the intention to "stop posting the data dump". If that wasn't the case, why not announce that back when the decision was made, and why announce a reversal of the stop only after the community writes extensively about it?

This reads rather like damage mitigation, and my trust in the company not doing it again anytime soon is still really close to or at zero.

This is just my personal opinion, but stopping the data dumps even if it caused only a delay in the end is still a bad sign. One doesn't need to stop a service in order to research it, and the company should know very well how important the data dumps are to the community. At the very least, this shows a certain disinterest in the feature.

Comment: I actually missed that the answer by Philippe has also been posted here, because when I saw it over there I stopped searching. So I quoted it in this answer. Maybe not so much point in it now, but also shows that cross-postings maybe aren't the best idea.

Comment: Note that [the phrasing of this statement was amended by Catija](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/390200/3), apparently to make Philippe's actual intent more clear, to say that their "_intention was never to stop posting the data dump **permanently**_". Skepticism is certainly justified; I do feel like that message is pretty in line with [the original statement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390040) on the matter, however, which said from the beginning it was a measure "until guardrails were put into place"... for as much value as that was worth at the time.

Comment: @zcoop98 I'm also skeptic about the guardrails, the corresponding question convinced me that it's basically impossible and I don't see any urgency. The data dump isn't a risk for anyone it's just the common possession of all contributors who collect their contributions there (or let them be collected to be precise but that is part of the deal).

Answer (score 15):

*Note*: This was directed to @Philippe about his [Q&A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390201/what-is-the-current-june-2023-status-of-the-data-dumps-and-the-company-s-commi/390202#390202) that was then merged into this question.

I know this is futile but I'll ask anyway:

1. Do you care whatsoever to address the blatant contradiction between your arguments about the intentions and those provided previously by the CTO? If we assume good faith, which is becoming more and more hard, this is an organizational and managerial mess and if we assume bad faith, someone is not being transparent.
2. Do you care to address why you didn't tell the community anything about this for about 2/3 months from the original decision until it was apparently leaked by a former employee?

On a separate note: Why isn't this featured?

Answer (score 9):

**Disclaimer**: sorry, the current format is due to a merge, and originally this was a reply to the linked company post.

---

So, let's look at the [official reply](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390200/171199).

> Much has been written lately of the company’s decision to pause the distribution of the anonymized data dump that has historically been posted.

Personally I have nothing to say here, but I can see foresee some users pointing out that the chosen wording seems to imply that it was the userbase specifically that said *too much* about the issue and hallucinated conspiracies that did not exist (before this message the company limited all interaction to just [one post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390040/171199)). Therefore I accept that this could feel a little condescending to some, but in my opinion I would just ignore it.

> Our intention was never to stop posting the data dump, only to begin to collect more information on how it was being used and by whom - especially in light of the rise of LLMs and questions around how genAI models are handling attribution.

This is in direct contrast with [the information the community got before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390040/171199) from the company CTO that said

> We are looking for ways to gate access to the Dump, APIs, and SEDE,
> that will allow individuals access to the data while preventing misuse
> by organizations looking to profit from the work of our community

It is a similar, but different message. It is also worth noticing that if the intent was indeed "begin to collect more information on how it was being used"

- I don't see how you could do that while the dump was not accessible anymore.
- I don't see why you should do that without any warning.

But wait! **Maybe that was the test? Getting data about how long it would take to the community to notice?** If that was your plan, great! Now we know that someone in the community is using the dump and will notice when it goes missing.

That said, there is also another logical association some will probably make. This happened about at the same time [the company announced to the press some plan about the monetization of the data dump](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388551/is-se-going-to-be-selling-our-content-for-ai-model-training-and-what-exactly).

> However, it’s clear that many individual users (academics, researchers, etc) have an immediate need to access updated versions of the dumps. So we are re-enabling the automatic data dumps (and uploading the one that’s about a week overdue).

Again, I won't argue here, but I'll let you know that this reads a tad like "But since you folk can't wait five minutes [...]". The problem is not the wait; the problem is that the stop came out of nowhere since you "forgot" to announce it and even if you probably are not legally bound to provide said data, users still expect to be warned if the implicit agreement changes.

> We believe that this can happen by end of the day Friday. We will continue to work toward the creation of certain guardrails (for large AI/LLM companies) for both the dumps and the API, but again - we have no intention of restricting/charging community members or other responsible users of the dumps or the API from accessing them.

I fear you... can't? Either you provide the dump "as is" and nothing can stop anyone to repost it even if the original download required a login or you try to "watermark" it in some way that would workaround the current license and make it a derivative work that would not be reproducible, but in that case... That is not the dump anymore.

> As part of this project, API users should be on the lookout for a very brief survey that will be coming out (announced here and on stackapps.com) that asks about the features that you most use/would like to see in the API or data dumps moving forward so that we can plan for those, as well as collect general input.
>
> In the meantime, the data dumps will be re-enabled by end of day Friday. We will communicate here when that has been completed or if there are any delays. We will also post here prior to making any future changes to the dumps or distribution of the dumps.

Fine, I guess. Why wasn't this the original way to go?

### Conclusions

This announcement leaves me with some mixed feelings. 
On the front, this seems like a "victory" for rationality—the dump has been restored, everything is fine now and you even promised to work on a solution together (albeit in the form of a survey).

Yet, in the current circumstances of the ongoing strike, I can't help but feel like this has been "staged" in some way as a part of a bigger strategy to show that the company did its part to "reach out" to the moderators on strike and now they should do their part to unless they are "bad actor with an agenda to prolong a conflict that the company was trying to solve rapidly".

The decision to shut down the dump seems to precede the strike and that was confirmed by a neutral third party—an ex-employee, so the things should not be related.  But at the same time, this victory only restores the initial status quo without any real gain for the community. With this stunt, the company has managed to "do its part toward an agreement" without actually changing anything, and now it feels only expected that the moderators should concede, "*do their part*" on something too. To put it bluntly, while it makes little sense if we assume all the related information the community got are accurate, all manages to feel very strategical and in a way even convenient for the company.

Comment: I would modify '*from another staff member that said*' to '*from the CTO that said*' as that's quite important considering the position of person that posted it as opposed to it being *just another employee*.

Comment: The last two paragraphs are so spot on that I really wish you'd open a separate question for it.

Comment: @Script47 done, thanks

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question of "will Stack Exchange eventually charge for API or data dump use", this can be found in the WIRED article from April 20th: [Stack Overflow Will Charge AI Giants for Training Data](https://www.wired.com/story/stack-overflow-will-charge-ai-giants-for-training-data/)

It has such passages as:

> Stack Overflow’s decision to seek compensation from companies tapping its data, part of a broader generative AI strategy, has not been previously reported. It follows an announcement by Reddit this week that it will begin charging some AI developers to access its own content starting in June.

and contains information on company direction from the CEO:

> “Community platforms that fuel LLMs absolutely should be compensated for their contributions so that companies like us can reinvest back into our communities to continue to make them thrive,” Stack Overflow’s Chandrasekar says. “We're very supportive of Reddit’s approach.”

> Chandrasekar described the potential additional revenue as vital to ensuring Stack Overflow can keep attracting users and maintaining high-quality information. He argues that will also help future chatbots, which need “to be trained on something that's progressing knowledge forward. They need new knowledge to be created.” But fencing off valuable data also could deter some AI training and slow improvement of LLMs, which are a threat to any service that people turn to for information and conversation. Chandrasekar says proper licensing will only help accelerate development of high-quality LLMs.

Comment: Thanks! But this was [discussed at the time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388551/308065), and isn't really relevant to _this_ question.

Comment: It was, and people seem to have missed it and have questions about the company direction or expecting the next step to "full Reddit and asking payment for API usage" or statements like "This is deeply concerning. If the next step is making all API access paid, I'm going to resign."  For people making those statements, that should be seen as inevitable rather than just possible.

Comment: Some people making those statements have access to behind-the-scenes information that you are not party to. It's not _entirely_ hopeless yet. Several things are basically set in stone, but I don't think "make all API access paid" is one of them.

Comment: That was clearly the case that none of the recent decisions have caught any of those who have closer access to staff channels off guard.  And for those who *do* have that access and such statements have been made in those channels, they tend to be *very* tight lipped about any of the goings on there until the company makes those changes public.  Or that previous appeals to the upper management for issues have resulted in significant changes or about faces to planned operations after such statements have been made to the press, investors, and parent companies.

Comment: Okay, but the article you're citing is from 1⅔ months ago. I feel like quoting it here (now that the context of the Reddit situation has changed) is misleading. Regardless, it neither answers the question nor responds to the CTO's answer. Stack Exchange sites – even meta – are not general forums. Please read the [tour].

Answer (score -104):

Stack Overflow senior leadership is working on a strategy to protect Stack Overflow data from being misused by companies building LLMs. While working on this strategy, we decided to stop the dump until we could put guardrails in place.

We are working on setting up the infrastructure to do this correctly in the age of LLMs --- where we continue to be open and share the data with our developer community but work to set up a formal framework for large AI companies that want to leverage the data.

We are looking for ways to gate access to the Dump, APIs, and SEDE,  that will allow individuals access to the data while preventing misuse by organizations looking to profit from the work of our community. We are working to design and implement appropriate safeguards and still sorting out the details and timelines. We will provide regular updates on our progress to this group.

---

**UPDATE:** [See this post for an update from Philippe.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390200)

Comment: Are you planning to keep all current uses of the dump, API and SEDE except training of LLMs available? Or will there be more restrictions that are expected to also disallow some other existing uses of the data?

Comment: In order to prevent companies building LLMs from getting our data (which they already have, and have had for years) your plan is to keep all of us from getting our data, am I reading that right?

Comment: Just as context for casual readers since it may not be obvious, Jody is our CTO. (I am not commenting on the matter at hand, just providing this info.)

Comment: Why are you not doing this openly? This concerns the data provided by the community; why are you not letting the community have a say in how this data is protected against misuse? Why don't you use our knowledge for this purpose? Excluding us from the process only brings anger, negative speculations, and mistrust. We get so much negative by doing it this way, when we could've cooperated, and gotten so much good from it instead. What is your motivation for not including us in the process? Why is there no transparency in this?

Comment: Why was this not stated in March, when the decision was made to turn off future data dumps? Or, even better, why was this not _discussed_ to get _feedback_ from impacted members of the community to better assess the risks of turning off the data dump versus not turning off the data dump?

Comment: **So you could say that.** You say that now only because you were caught red handed, that's what I think.

Comment: Also, it's not "Stack Overflow data". The content here is our data that we have chosen to license. So perhaps the creators and owners of that data should be more involved in making decisions about how their data is distributed.

Comment: This question has been sitting on Meta for two days. This answer would look more credible if it was the first one posted. Now it just looks like poor damage control. And even then there is still a question why has this not been communicated before?

Comment: *"misuse by organizations looking to profit from the work of our community"* ─ I hope this means you won't start charging for API access, because most of us would consider that a misuse by an organisation looking to profit from our work.

Comment: "organizations looking to profit from the work of our community" — that's funny when you say it like that, you know :)

Comment: [How can SE gate access to the Dump that will allow individuals access to the data while preventing "misuse" by for-profit organizations?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390043/178179)

Comment: How can data licensed under the CC-BY-SA licenses that SE content is licensed under be "misused"? The license *explictly allows* others to do essentially anything they want with the data as long as attribution is given, in particular *profit off of it*. It can't be "misused*, the users can only fail to give attribution or follow the share-alike requirement. It is entirely unclear in what ways restricting access to the data would improve the situation with respect to attribution.

Comment: As other comments said... First, why waiting (again) for someone to "catch you red handed". Second, how this fits in with the question [Is SE (....) selling our content for AI model training? And what exactly does "reinvest back into our communities" mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388551/is-se-going-to-be-selling-our-content-for-ai-model-training-and-what-exactly). Does this imply a change of plan or should be interpreted as an action to avoid others getting for free the data you plan to sell?

Comment: How can you gate what people who you give the dump to do when the license explicitly renders such restrictions void? https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/11067/what-does-no-additional-restrictions-of-the-cc-by-license-mean-when-selling-a
You can ask people what they will do with it and stop giving it to them. But you can't implement 'safeguards' without restricting who has access significantly.

Comment: I really, really want to take this at full face value. I also think the Company really needs to understand how important this data dump is to the community, and **how easy it is to read this as a message that the dumps are "temporarily postponed" indefinitely, and will never return**. I don't think the Company gets to have the benefit of the doubt with messaging like this, this week of all weeks... I _beg_ you bear in mind how the messaging comes across, and how easy it feels, from the outside, to read this as a way to misdirect and soften the blow of doing away with the data dumps for good.

Comment: Please just release it and let those AIs choke on it. Your estimates in the data post _are_ off by orders of magnitude. AI posts are way more rampant than you publicly dare to admit. Let them feed that AI-generated nonsense back into their algorithms and watch the trend burn, please.

Comment: What happened to at least giving heads-up that something like this was going to happen? That's what *community* used to mean. This new way of just doing stuff without any communication isn't the best community experience

Comment: Of course. The last thing anyone wants is some *commercial organisation* seeking to profit off the work of the community.

Comment: *"We are looking for ways to gate access to the Dump, APIs, and SEDE, that will allow individuals access to the data while preventing misuse by organizations looking to profit from the work of our community."* - Do you not see the irony of this statement when for years your power users and mods have been complaining about SO doing the same garbage.

Comment: Those AI and LLM trainers you pretend to be concerned about? They'll just screen scrape, that's easy for them to do, remove the HTML and maybe the scripts and styles and... you've got language left. But the rest of the community? Screen scraping is a lot tougher and more fragile for the rest of us.

Comment: @DimeCadmium Stack Overflow _claims_ copyright over the aggregation. Which is weird, since we're the ones doing all the moderation (the actual work of curating the aggregation); surely _we_ have the copyright, there? I was happy to not question it, and permit this polite fiction, but that was when we had the data dumps.

Comment: Is there any reason you think the data dumps would be the way that LLMs have used SE training data, versus crawling/scraping the site? I would have assumed the latter, since then they can use the same tool over many sites versus digesting the SE data format specifically.

Comment: “No downstream restrictions. You may not offer or impose any additional or different terms or conditions on, or apply any Effective Technological Measures to, the Licensed Material if doing so restricts exercise of the Licensed Rights by any recipient of the Licensed Material.”

Comment: Friendly reminder for those commenting on the licensing: While I'm not a lawyer, I think that [Stack Exchange content is dual-licensed](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/5663/do-stack-exchange-s-tos-mean-that-the-user-generated-content-is-double-licensed), so only looking at the Creative Commons license is somewhat less useful in this specific case.

Comment: I'm all for ensuring that the community gets credit for the contribution to LLM training of material we've written. But is there really reason to believe that the data dumps, SEDE, and the API are actually how they're getting this information, rather than web scraping?  Consider, for example, that OpenAI is closely partnered with Microsoft, which operates a large search engine. Unless the restrictions you impose are *very* specific to LLM training, I fear this will hurt the community (and by extension, the company supported by its work) more than it helps via increased funding or attribution.

Comment: A good time to have announced this change was back in April when the CEO addressed the concern with LLMs using Stack Overflow data. There was even [a handy meta question about it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388551/is-se-going-to-be-selling-our-content-for-ai-model-training-and-what-exactly). Hoping nobody would notice was never a good idea.

Comment: "misuse by organizations looking to profit from the work of our community" Profiting from the work of the community is not misuse. Through the CC BY-SA license, we have authorized anyone to use our content for any purpose, including commercial purposes.

Comment: @Someone-OnStrike Profiting from the work of the community _without attribution_ is misuse, though. (Sadly, that's not what the company is defending against.)

Comment: By "guard rails" apparently you mean making sure the dump is actually quality training data. Ironically disabling new dumps is probably the best way you could have accomplished the *opposite* of your stated goals with ML… with your new policies any new dumps are going to be inreasingly poluted with LLM generated content anyway, so that's the most valuable dump there will be going forward until you add back the one guard rail the whole community has clamoured for: no generated content in the human currated data set!

Comment: "We are looking for ways to gate access to the Dump, APIs, and SEDE, that will allow individuals access to the data while preventing misuse by organizations looking to profit from the work of our community." As a StackExchange contributor, I _want_ organizations to be able to use my work to train AI models which benefit humanity. Critically, I want _all_ organizations to have this ability, not merely a select few who can pay for the privilege!

Comment: *"preventing misuse by organizations looking to profit from the work of our community"* Our community? Does SE Inc own the community? Which organization is profiting most from the work of the community? Is there a list and which organization would be on top with how much money? How does SE inc., which obviously profits from the community and would not exist without it, compare to those organizations?

Comment: *"Stack Overflow data from being misused by companies building LLMs."* What misuse? How is building LLMs based on human conversations a misuse of data? SE/SO is all about helping other people and teach them how to solve simple questions. If a LLN uses it to learn how people answer questions then this has nothing to do with copyright infringement or other misuse. Millions of people are reading posts on SE/SO and incorporate the methods of answering into their vocabulary such that the next time that they answer a question themselves they will be able to answer more eloquently.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus let me translate the corp-speak into common tongue speech real quick, it means: "they are not paying us money for that data". Not worth wasting keystrokes on what "misuse" means, we all know what it really refers to.

Comment: This is really problematic on so many levels. At the very least, you needed to announce it in advance. Not just for decency, but also to meet your committed responsibilities to the community. You must assume that anyone who contributed to date did so relying on SE Inc's past firm commitments to upload data. I don't see how you avoid sharing this dump, and probably the next one - in full - without incurring some form of legal liability. Protecting against such claims means releasing dumps that include any posts made before the announcement. So there's no point holding it while you work.

Comment: @ACuriousMind which LLM companies give attribution for their data sources? Or open-source their results? The correct solution, and the point of having a license, is to sue them. Not to make it harder for everyone to get the data.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus because they don't follow the license and neither BY nor SA.

Comment: @OrangeDog who is *they* that you are referring to and *how* do they not comply with licensing? Who is copying outside of terms like fair usage? Is it the AI-companies? That is not very well motivated. Can you ask something to chatGPT and it answers with a copy of SE/SO Q&A's? A LLM is just copying the content to it's artificial brain, it is not re-publishing the work. It is not anything different from humans copying questions and answers into the neurons of their brains (and when humans re-use parts of the information they dont give attribution either unless they copy something substantial).

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus yes, the AI implementations. Yes, when ChatGPT tells you something it is republishing. Just the same as an SO proxy site. It doesn't give attribution for where it copied it from, so is not compliant with the license. Nor does it licence its modifications under CC BY-SA.

Comment: @OrangeDog I also have been training my brain on SE data. Do I need to give attribution to all my training sources for every sentence that I write?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus if what you're writing is taken from an SE post, then yes. You also have to license it under compatible terms.

Comment: @OrangeDog everything that I write originates indirectly from others (including every SE post that I have ever read). My brain is one big copy machine that reads math books, looks at art, and listens to music and creates copies (transformed into impressions) by storing it into a network of neurons. All that copied content indirectly ends up in whatever I express as my brain is taking continuously these trained bits of impressions when I generate output (actions) in response to my environment. As long as I don't reproduce whole essential pieces then the CC-BY license used here doesn't apply.

Comment: @Jody can you comment on MO data as distinct from the rest of the SE network?

Comment: SE doesn't own the data. The users do. And we've licensed it to Stack Exchange under  CC BY-SA 4.0 (or earlier versions). This answer makes me concerned Stack Exchange is breaking the license terms.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus and LLMs do reproduce whole pieces

Comment: I miss the days when we could have a conversation about these statements and the questions and comments were getting responses from the staff. Now, we only get one statement, one that is way too general, way too political, and pretty darn late. After that, radio silence.

Comment: To prevent building LLMs? The previous dumps already contain several million q/a's the new dump only a few 100k extra. Likely the extra data does not matter that much to build an LLM...

Comment: @Gloweye For the record, [there is a separate question about that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390137/is-se-in-violation-of-the-cc-by-sa-4-0-license-by-not-providing-data-dumps); the consensus seems to be no.