What should the policy for AI-generated images be on Meta.SE?
I locked this post earlier this evening because an AI-generated image was edited out, then back in, then out, in-out... giving major hokey-pokey vibes. It seems there are different opinions on whether the current GenAI policy for Meta.SE should be applied to all 'content', or just 'text'.
The policy using both interchangeably isn't making it any more useful in deciding what to allow or not allow in this case: A case for both interpretations can be made. I'll make a follow-up post about the help center article wording later; let's first get some consensus on whether images should be allowed or not at all, no matter what the help center can be interpreted as saying.
We did have a discussion about AI/LLM generated texts for Meta SE, but we don't have one specific for images yet. So: Should AI-generated imagery be allowed in posts on Meta SE? And if no, should it be a total ban or should there be exceptions for non-essential/fun images, or things like perhaps staff announcements?

@wizzwizz4 Not sure why CMs would need to monitor the voting in real time, or how some people holding off on voting is going to affect whether they feel pressure to check in or not. I'm actually not sure the company needs to weigh in on this at all, it seems like a localized site policy?

On Meta, the first couple answers and the first few votes often set the tone of entire discussions, and it snowballs easily. This can be challenging to overcome in a community that frequently has to stop, step back, think, and take a level-headed/neutral approach to evaluating a problem. Only then can people develop a plan and fairly assess a complement of solutions around it. But in an environment where participating productively means participating early, I think many people try to be among the first to speak, on the notion that getting anything out soon is better than going unheard later.

Reserving voting until the discussion has time to develop is an admirable goal, as is trying to help shape the discussion by stepping in early. But ultimately the former is a bit doomed (you can't really stop people from voting) and the latter has a bit of a tendency to result in hasty solutions. But - ah, well. These are the limitations we work with here. I hope no one, employee or otherwise, feels the need to check in on this discussion over the weekend ;) (Also, I don't mean this as a callout to Cesar. I genuinely think his answer is useful.)

For people who just want to avoid the whole genAI image thing, you can find suitable images at Pexels or Wikimedia (which have appropriate copyright for use at Stack Exchange).

I would be interested in knowing how the image in question in any way detracted from the post. When one relies solely on the principle of an argument (such as being anti-technology), the outcomes are often draconian and ultimately hurt desired outcomes. I think that's the case here.  The image simply adds levity via the addition of a meme to a very serious answer. Stack Overflow is riddled with memes. Early Stack Overflow was built on a foundation of memes. If folks want to squeeze out the last semblance of joy from posts, go for it. I'm sure it'll really help with site health. /snark

@AMtwo I could just as well ask what useful information that image added to the post. I suppose I haven't been around long enough, but I honestly have no clue what it's supposed to say. I guess that's the problem with memes -- you've got to be "in" to get them. But really, the topic in question doesn't seem like one where lighthearted content helps anything. (Like, if it was an AI generated diagram of the infrastructure, I'd have some understanding, but... what was that about?)

@dan as a meme, it's a joke. It brings a smile. Just because you don't get a joke doesn't mean others don't appreciate it.  A brief website outage isn't a death. The DBRE team had a database outage and made a joke while explaining what happened. If it's problematic, then there should be a tangible reason it should be retracted. If it's not problematic, then it's just a bad joke, and swatting it down only serves to yuk someone else's yum.

Maybe related Why do we hate fun at Stack Exchange?

The princess had two right arms in the pic. Clearly a reason to remove it.

@AMtwo I suppose, I didn't engage in removing it, but it just didn't seem relevant there. (Although it is a weird AI generated thing that tried to look like pixel art but completely missed the point, but whatever) Honestly it's kinda hard to understand what this site wants to be... on one hand this nonsense is just fine and defended by people... on the other hand you try to have a discussion, and some keener deletes half of the comments because they (I guess) don't like them. Seems a bit like double standards.

Another example, from DIY    https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/310528/revisions    The image is relevant because the poster created it to match, but it adds nothing to the answer other than attracting potential upvotes.   Answers with useful images seem to score higher than similar answers without images, and this one "looks" relevant.

I don't think AI-generated images are problematic in the same way that AI-generated text is for our sites. I'd consider this almost an entirely separate topic, both are about generative AI but the situations are very different in all other aspects.
The kind of image you can create using generative AI is also rarely used in posts on SE sites, here on MSE might even be the most likely case as superfluous images are allowed, or at least tolerated sometimes. So this is really more an edge case and not a fundamental issue in the same way as generative AI for text generation is.
So this is essentially the "meh" answer, I can live with both options and don't have a particularly strong preference. I personally wouldn't have removed that image, but I agree that given the current policy it is either forbidden or ambiguous. Simply disallowing genAI images might be a simpler policy, which is a benefit. But I don't think genAI images are harmful in a way here on MSE that would require a policy to remove them, we already remove images if they are too distracting.

I don't think we need a blanket ban on AI-generated images.
Regardless of one's views on LLMs and similar image models, they don't cause harm here, particularly in cases like the example where it's just comedic relief on an otherwise serious answer. Given how prevalent AI-generated images are... it's going to become difficult to find such images that aren't AI-generated.

I want to provide my personal input on how I think this discussion can best be structured. I'm going to divide it into 3 different categories (that can be further divided into more, but I'm going to start more broadly).
No, nothing GenAI is allowed, at all.

This is the easiest and clearest version to enforce. It is a blanket ban on all forms of GenAI content; nothing is an exception, and that's the end.

Useful GenAI images are allowed, nothing else

This is an exception for GenAI images that are useful, meaning that they actively add something important to the post at hand, and not including them would be a detriment to the post.
[There are possible further ways to slice this, like being more restrictive in that it needs to be useful and not easily replaced with something that isn't GenAI. Or more liberal in that only GenAI text is fully banned but other forms of GenAI may be allowed if useful]

GenAI images are allowed, unless misleading

This allows GenAI images to be used in most cases, including funny things. It may be reasonable to require disclosure, but given disclosure, it isn't forbidden. This is also the most in line with the current restrictions of the CoC in its misleading information policy (i.e., it's not okay to post images/videos/quotes in a way that misleads the reader).

Now, I'm not saying the site needs to adopt any of the 3 specifically. Personally, at first, I'd go with the last one for MSE specifically. But that's my personal take and not my staff "I'm asking you to do this" take.

So, you're proposing that if this one ends up top, we're putting the third into policy? Or how am I supposed to interpret the voting here in the future? :) interpreting votes gets a bit tricky if there are three options in one post

@Tinkeringbell Can we interpret it as some combination of "This answer is useful" and "Meta is weird"?

@Tinkeringbell no I'd go more towards Bryan's heh. I don't think we should take any binding interpretations towards the direction that the policy should go based on this answer, no. Mostly I wanted to provide a (hopefully) helpful structure to help the discussion happen.

@CesarM ah cool, have my vote too then :)

I would say that GenAI images are almost always misleading. It doesn't get the proportions of people right, it replicates stereotypes and invents exciting new ones, it draws pictures of birds that aren't any species, and in doing so, erodes the subconscious bird intuition of the casual viewer… Currently, Stack Exchange is somewhat of a portal to the world, in the same way an illustrated encyclopedia is. I'm concerned that any policy that allows GenAI images will erode that.

@wizzwizz4 I think how misleading something is depends on what it's meant to represent and how it's overall presented. I mean, can you have a misleading picture of a dragon or some other fictional entity? Probably not. Similarly anything where you're referring to the image itself rather than it's contents. I'm having trouble thinking of use cases, but maybe lets say I want to demonstrate the concept of "contrast" and ask AI to generate me a low contrast and high contrast image. The contents of the image don't really matter, if they show the principle then that's all they need to do.

@wizzwizz4 I think that's a good and fair point. And to add to it, I think that's not a problem specific to GenAI though, right? A huge part of artists training is getting proportions right, it isn't easy and many people don't. What about art movements such as surrealism, absurdism, and cubism? Is The Scream misleading? I think that's a more ontological debate that largely depends on context. The advertisement industry, for example, has changed beauty standards; those are real videos of real people. Should they be banned for being misleading?

It might be that on some sites, or on a natural sciences course, it makes sense not to allow them because of the subtle effect pictures can have on our subconscious intuitions. But I think to just say they are "almost always" misleading, while true, doesn't do justice to the fact that many other things are in the sense that they don't represent real everyday proportions. I'd say this is largely context-dependent, and where the accuracy of those things matters, sure. But that isn't always the case.

A work communicates more (and, often, less) than what the author intended. Images sourced from somewhere have an original context, and can be viewed in terms of that. GenAI output has no "original context" (unless you're a particular kind of sociologist). Ungrounded hyperreality is bad, and we should take measures to avoid it, even when the harms aren't immediately obvious.

I suspect applied discussion on the grounds of what forms of art are or are not intrinsically, societally acceptable are gonna stall out. Because... well, some form of this argument has been floating around in a modern context since at least 1935 when Walther Benjamin argued in The Work of Art in the Age of Mechanical Reproduction that manufactured (printed, copied, etc) art loses its "aura of authenticity," depriving it of its cult value and turning its value into that of a commodity or exhibition.

If this sounds a bit nebulous, well, it is. What I mean to say is that arguments (in wider society) about the core ethic of art have really only been successful when a harm has been quite concrete and named clearly, e.g. propaganda, beauty standards in advertising, and the like. So if there's a core harm on which to base a policy, it has to be named clearly and grounded in real, demonstrable outcomes. Then the policy restricts the undesirable outcomes by name, leaving restrictions on content implied. This will take thought, and strikes me as more complex than it might seem at first glance.

I'm leaning towards another option: "GenAI images should be allowed, unless useful" — and I mean that kind-of seriously. The primary unifying concern about GenAI text is about incorrect/misleading/poorly-vetted information. If a GenAI image is being used for an informational purpose, those same concerns apply, and it should be prohibited. But if it's just being used for flavor/fun, as image are sometimes used on meta, those concerns don't apply, and I think it should be allowed. (I recognize that many people have other concerns about GenAI content, but the unifying one was misinformation.)

@2024-10-01 I guess that's also possible haha. I'd make a new answer with that proposal if you want. That way it can be considered by folks and voted on :)

@CesarM I won't bother with an answer since Tinkeringbell pointed out that this distinction is largely irrelevant on MSE. :P

I think the problem with 'useful' is - well that's deeply subjective

They're extremely useful occasionally to illustrate a point on creative sites. It's not frequent, but I've used it myself on Worldbuilding and stand by that usage. Appropriate usage might need pinning down so we have a standard to reference.

SE's made a big deal about "Socially responsible AI". One would expect that if a company expects others to respect the rights of code creators to be recognised, it seems logical that where a LLM's trained with art - the artist should be recognised in the same way.
While as a community, it feels that we had a blind spot outside textual content in scoping out and defining rules for generative AI, in spirit I feel that we really can't exclude other forms of media - be it images, videos or audio.
Where generative AI content is allowed, I feel like anything the company puts out should follow the same principles it expects its partners and the community to follow, and unattributed generative AI work of any sort shouldn't be put out by staff, either on the network (where we can provide immediate feedback) or other properties it manages, and attribution should be down to the source of the training data.
I'd note that extending this rule to the community would essentially result in a defacto ban on any generative AI content, since no one actually attributes, so I'd leave that decision to the individual communities, but I feel that the company should be following.
One would guess there could be exceptions carved out, where such content is at the heart of a post - but that's beyond the scope of this post.

I'd say (on personal title, not as a mod) that AI-generated images should not be allowed on MSE. There are plenty of conundrums around AI-generated imagery, the most well known to me being that the models are being trained on copyrighted material, and I'd rather just avoid all of it by having no AI-generated content at all on the site.
The only exception I'd be willing to make would be if the image was somehow essential to staff showing us something in an announcement/for review/discussion by the community.

I think this position might be a bit problematic: (1) the ethics of AI generated images are divisive and many users may not agree. (2) the legality of AI generated images is disputed and unresolved in many cases. (3) there are some (admittedly not most) AI image models out there which uses ethically-sourced data which the most ethical and legal arguments would not apply to, but we can't immediately tell which images came from those. The basis for a ban is shaky, in contrast to AI generated text, where the risk of misinformation and spam was immediate, acute, and nearly-universally agreed-on.

The previous comment refers to a blanket ban, such as for the case discussed in the original question. I do support a ban for cases where the image is meant to convey actual information, where the concerns about misinformation do apply. Don't use a generated image of an animal for your biology post, or a generated image of a skyscraper when discussing architecture, or a generated image of  plants when discussing gardening. That should not be allowed. But if it's just for fun/flavor, such as where we'd tolerate someone using a meme or goofy image on meta, I think they should be allowed.

@2024-10-01 as I'm trying to get through to someone's skull in another comment thread. I'm asking for MSE only, not biology or gardening or whatever. If there are ever going to be questions open and answered and considered suitable for Meta.SE they'd better be tagged fun or something... Else they either need migrating or closing/deleting anyways, and in both cases the image or its provenance doesn't matter as it's either not an MSE problem anymore or gone. So unless you've got an example of "useful" on MSE .... I'd leave it out of the discussion here :)

You're right, I was getting a bit out-of-scope. For MSE we can probably ignore my second comment: I can't imagine any informative uses of images on MSE except for screenshots, so they're all for flavour/fun, and they should all be allowed.

Generally, a position of just not allowing it is in service of both those who are against it and for it. You can’t satisfy everyone, but it’s far less… annoying/frustrating for it to not exist for those who either don’t care or want to see them, than it is for those who wouldn’t or are significantly bothered by it to see it everywhere.

(As long as the enforcement isn’t excessively blunt)

Do you consider your own avatar to be AI-generated?

@RebeccaJ.Stones No. because I made it by taking elements from there, but I manually combined them and even added an element you won't find in the sources there. Unless the elements were AI-generated themselves (which then wouldn't be disclosed, it seems) it is not. Sorry to disappoint, but no hypocrisy on my part here AFAIK.

@Tinkeringbell --- I am 100% positive that the Stack Overflow logo on the taxi hood, "OpenID" roadsign, and "OPENID" license plate were all manually added by Aaron. By your own standard, this image should be allowed. Particularly in an announcement by a Staff member.

@AMtwo by my own standard? AFAIK, none of the elements that make up my avatar were AI generated, if they were I will be looking into something else soon, while "added by" implies there was AI generated content in the image that's prompted this discussion. Also, what/how does it matter that Aaron is staff when talking about allowing or not allowing AI-generated imagery on MSE?

Also, I'm not sure if discussing user avatars is helpful here... They're not posts. But they are content, that's true. If necessary, I can clarify the question and limit it to posts only: I wasn't planning on going around resetting profile images for this. As far as I know, profiles already go unmoderated for AI content, I have yet to hear of the first reset for having AI text or images there.

@RebeccaJ.Stones They are created by a PHP script which randomly combines different image parts. The source is provided on https://www.peppercarrot.com/extras/html/2019_bird-generator/README.php.

I feel like every time I check, it seems the definition of AI has changed.  (AI.SE has a post about it.)

@avpaderno and the script isn't the only way. I just downloaded the zip and stacked some elements in paint.net, editing one while I was at it. Apparently that makes "my own standard" one that allows AI generated imagery, according to AMtwo above. Oh well.... I guess that at least makes me intelligent, if only artificially....

@RebeccaJ.Stones If a PHP script combining images were AI, we would have had AI since 1994.

@Tinkeringbell I posted my comment just because the comment to which I replied seemed to say that, since there is a script randomly combining images, the created image can be considered an AI image. Indeed, you can just use the provided images to create your own image (as you did), and that would not be even an image created by a script.

@avpaderno: The Wikipedia page Timeline of artificial intelligence lists what AI was like in 1994.

@RebeccaJ.Stones PHP scripts are not used to write AI routines; If a PHP script combining images were AI, […].

just a little tidbit here, I agree with @RebeccaJ.Stones on a point. It would be probably better if GanGen was called GanGen, LLM were called LLM and the horrid "AI" term was reserved only to the very few tech that actually try to emulate intelligence...

@SPArcheon-onstrike What is "GanGen"?  I can find zero relevant results via a web search.

@RyanM oh, sorry, just slang - GAN based generated content. I was just ranting about how these marketing posts the company loves to post label EVERYTHING with the name AI... which most of the time means nothing.

TL;DR
The image that started this was used as a decorative element, not as relevant information, which usage I think is fine, but we mainly need a clearer policy either way.

Isn't the fundamental problem with AI-generated content that it hallucinates (and at the least requires human verification)?
To make my point, and that of the original intent of the image—and I'm not sure why as its precursor it is lacking from this entire 'thread'—this is the image in question (note that I'm quoting here, so it's okay!):


source

And it was used as an illustration of a playful analogy, namely that of the princess finally being freed after spending time in different castles (a reference to the well-established meme from Super Mario Bros.).*
My point being: the image had no bearing on the information that the message was intended to communicate. It was just a decoration, a light-hearted footnote to an otherwise transparent but jargon-heavy clarification of a recent network outage.
The current policy was clearly written with the idea in mind that the generated content would be text, and used as an answer. The broad word "content" is said to have been "written", "crafted [..] using a tool that writes" or "tools [that] are trained to answer", and its three major problems all go against long-established network policies that regulate the quality of information: genAI lacks human experience, it is easily accessible (similar to how LMGTFY would be a non-answer), and it cannot attribute its information. These issues don't matter when it comes to decorations.
While attribution might legally not be required, I think it would be good to include as a prerequisite for posting genAI imagery: it distinguishes the image from other content, and emphasises that whatever little can be gleaned from it still falls under the hallucinatory nature of the AI.
But I concur with Mad Scientist's answer: at this point I don't care much either way, except for a clearer policy.


* I'm not entirely sure I get the comparison, though, as the princess seems to both represent (access to) the SE network (excepting SO) as well as the specific "OpenID taxis" network cluster, and castle is both a single node and, given that the princess is happy and she must have escaped the castle, a locked-down cluster. Anyway.


If you've trained a graphical GenAI system on your own source media, or on public domain images, or on a ethically sourced data set that you are confident you can accurately cite, then such images should be allowed on SE sites (though which of these ethical sources you used should still be stated as otherwise people will assume you did not use an ethical GenAI.)
DALL-E, Midjourney, and other commercial GenAI systems were trained on unethical datasets, taking images from creators who did not consent, and cannot provide any attribution, meaning they are plagiarising. Like plagiarising text GenAI, these image AI generators have no place on the Stack Exchange network and should not be permitted. Not even company staff should have an exception.

“The current Firefly generative AI models were trained on a dataset of licensed content, such as Adobe Stock, and public domain content where copyright has expired. To ensure that creators can benefit from generative AI, we’ve developed a compensation model for Adobe Stock contributors whose content is used in the dataset to retrain Firefly models.”

@2024-10-01 As long as those contributors are publicly viewable, that does sound like an ethical GenAI model. Good to know.

I’m not sure how good the attribution actually is: Firefly might still be problematic, but it should be the “least bad” of current options.

s/unethical/illegal/

So far it appears that everybody here is missing a fairly big issue.
Generating an AI image uses more electricity than fully charging a smartphone
For a single image, that's no big deal, right? But Stack Exchange is big. Mind-bogglingly big. If AI generated images end up being the norm, or even just fairly common, the carbon footprint from SE's usage of AI continues to skyrocket.
Ethically and environmentally, this isn't a good look, folks.

People generate images anyway, regardless of one site or another. And if a site will ban something a person is used to do, that person would likely just avoid the site. Banning AI images here would not save the planet, and just drive away people for no good reason. To have actual impact, environment organizations should fight with all their might against GenAI in general, and prevent image generation in its very core, i.e. make it illegal to use.

Stack Exchange may be big, meta.stackexchange.com only though, not so much.

Does that mean every time a user gives prompts to an AI to generate one image that would be the equivalent of charging a single smartphone?  What would be  the equivalent in smartphone charging driving an electric car 30km  a day? Is it less?

The energy consumption is concerning, but this claim is probably an atypical upper bound, if anything. Per the paper that's presumably the source of this claim: "the least efficient image generation model uses [...] around half a charge per image generation". Weirdly, MIT Technology Review rounds this up to a full charge. The paper doesn't describe any of the parameters they used, which is a pretty major shortcoming since in my experience that can affect energy use by 10x. These folks need to do do higher-quality research if they want to shift the discourse. Lousy vague papers help nothing.

Allow AI images that are cited
Meta is a bit different than the main site, and many of the issues with genAI text are less of an issue with images on Meta. People monitor MSE a lot, so there's a lot of eyes on what happens here. IMO, there's less of a risk of abuse of it compared to text, so I'm not against giving it a try. We can always change policy later.
That said, I think these images should be cited with text like "This image was generated by [service]", because it's from something else, but also it's policy.

Can images be cited? It's one thing to say who did the generation, but then you're left with the usual questions of attribution for training data.

GenAI attributing training images would amount to a .txt file listing maybe billions of images ("Source: basically every image on the Internet"), which I don't think would be useful to normal users of Stack Exchange (unless maybe they're making their own genAI), nor to any artist.  I don't think this is a reasonable standard to set.  It also raises the question: should genAI have different attribution standards to humans?  No human is asked to attribute every image they've ever seen.

@RebeccaJ.Stones Indeed, that's not reasonable. I was thinking more along the lines of This image was generated by (service), as that seems better than nothing. Also, text content (by default, excluding per-site policy) is supposed to be attributed, so I was thinking something along those lines.

@Rebecca You could train an GenAI image generator on your own data, or on public domain images, or on an ethically sourced image set. Only the unethical AI companies result in AI systems that would necessitate citing billions of sources.

It doesn't matter who/what creates the image. Therefore, machine-generated images are ok, as long as they are not breaking any rules (license, attribution, content, etc.) just like for any other image.

But how can machine generated images not break licenses or attribution?

@NoDataDumpNoContribution eg using public domain images.

First, for the given example, surely the image should be deleted because it's a salutation, i.e., it's an image equivalent of "hello", and deleting salutations is a longstanding norm.  There's also an argument it should be deleted for self-promotion, since the problematic image has the Stack Overflow logo (if the logo were instead for McDonald's, then it'd probably get flagged as spam).  If the author instead had drawn the image by hand, would that change anything?  I don't think so.

As for the question, before we decide on (dis)allowing AI-generated images, we should probably get a clearer idea of what an AI-generated image actually is, because this is far from obvious: different people have different understandings of this concept.
Modern AI image generation
Nowadays, we can put a phrase like "an elephant riding a unicycle" into an online AI generator and get an image.  In all likelihood the first images you get will be awful, like this one by leonardo.ai.  Maybe this is what people are generally envisaging when discussing deleting genAI images.  I don't have any qualms about deleting such near-zero-effort pointless images here (Meta.SE), especially if they needlessly clutter up the place.
(At the same time, I urge people to make such deletions carefully: Meta.SE users in particular express themselves in creative ways, and generally we respect the authors' intentions while editing.  Since deleting other people's images is a form of censorship, we need to make sure we're not deleting anything meaningful and inhibiting people from expressing themselves.  And I find it's best to be a bit flexible and tolerant with these things, so that we can get along better; we used to have fun, y'know.)
I want to point out that many images are modified by AI, not wholly generated by AI.  E.g., at leonardo.ai, there's a scroll bar:



Here, "Strength: 1" implies the original image is unmodified, and "Strength: 0" implies the original image is ignored.  So where's the cut-off?
When you want an AI-generated image (a good one), you might first make a draft by hand, then let the AI turn it into a polished image.  For example, SirBenet's answer here shows what AI image generation might look like using ComfyUI:


Note: I redacted the AI content in this image (since it's currently unclear if it's allowed or not); the unredacted image shows three cups that look realistic.  Please see SirBenet's answer for the actual final image.

Often one image is carefully chosen from a large number of AI-generated images (possibly with multiple iterations).  A user might select a portion of an image and get an AI to edit that, or the user might just edit an AI-generated image manually.  So while there's AI-generated images which took seconds to generate, there's also AI-generated images which took human time and expertise to generate.
Images containing AI content
We used to post procedurally drawn images without any problems:



Many users have still have procedurally drawn avatars, e.g.:



and they regularly appear in screenshots in Meta.SE posts, e.g. here and here.  I consider these procedurally drawn images to be AI-generated images I think I've changed my mind about this: there are images generated by algorithms which should not be considered "AI generated" (like gravatars), which makes me want to rethink the whole definition on the AI policy page...
The AI policy defines "content generated by generative artificial intelligence tools" as follows:

“Content generated by generative artificial intelligence tools” is any content crafted, in part or in whole, using a tool that writes a response automatically based on a prompt it is provided.

So there's an issue with the word "writes" here (the policy was written in haste to combat copy/paste ChatGPT spam at the time); normally we'd use the verb "generates" for an AI generating an image.  So there's two interpretations here:

The AI policy does not include AI-generated images in its scope.
The spirit of the word "writes" is more like "generates", since an AI cannot actually "write" anything anyway.

It's a bit of an unfortunate technicality.  If the second interpretation holds (and the AI policy applies to AI-generated images), then the above procedurally generated images would be classified as "content generated by generative artificial intelligence tools".
In any case, all five questions tagged ai-enhanced-search contain AI-generated text in the form of a screenshot (likewise for this answer).  And the choice of the word "writes" is definitely applicable here.  Despite the AI-generated content, I'm fairly sure any reasonable person would consider these posts unproblematic.
So surely there are times when images containing AI-generated content should be considered permissible at Meta.SE, especially in posts like this:



But then we have to figure out whose definitions we should go by, and how flexibly we should apply the rules.
How can we infer from an image posted at Meta.SE the inner workings of the algorithm used to produce it, and determine whether or not it involves AI in the generation process?  (After all, some image-generation algorithms are AI, some aren't.)
We have high standards (involving heuristics; not publicly known) for detecting AI-generated text, should we not have equally high standards for AI-generated images?
I also worry that AI is becoming so ubiquitous, that it's likely I'm using it without realizing.  E.g., if I take a photo, maybe there is some AI-based filter in my software that I'm not even aware of.  I do not know whether or not my drawing software uses AI.
TL;DR:  I'm okay with deleting the nonsense AI-generated images.  But what's the definition of an AI-generated image?  Apparently, I got it wrong.  But nobody has given me an alternative.  Is the definition the same as in the AI policy, but with "generates" instead of "writes"?

...any content crafted, in part or in whole, using a tool that writes a response automatically based on a prompt it is provided


"procedurally drawn images" is not "AI", and "AI" is not "generative AI". We've been using "AI" assistant systems for a very long time (one example that comes up in coding contexts is spell checkers) with no issues. Generative AI and their applications are a novel can of worms, and pretending they aren't is missing the core concerns around generative AI.

Yeah, spell checkers (and many other AIs like speech-to-text, autocomplete, Google Translate) were unproblematic.  ChatGPT has these functionalities too, yet, to my knowledge, it's banned.  Grammarly was deemed okay at Stack Overflow but it has been implementing genAI features.  So it's quite unclear what's allowed and what's not allowed.  It seems like the original aim was to prevent mindlessly copy/pasting ChatGPT crap (which was genuinely harming sites), and now mission creep has kicked in.

I think it's more about not being able to fine-tune rules in a way that's hard to explain and enforce. Even well-meaning users might disagree in what "spell checking functionality" entails. For sure some users would assume that a full rewrite is in the same category. Of course I don't know if this was explicitly considered, but I see how it's the most robust approach to flat-out ban any use of LLMs.

A Reddit post describes AI art process in greater detail than me.

"Professional AI art". That's hilarious!

People used to (maybe still do?) make fun of all forms of digital art, saying it's "not real art".  There's probably still people around who think photography is just pushing a button.  It's not very nice.

This question is based on a false premise. The assumption is that MSE, or any site on the network, can unilaterally develop its own GenAI policy. I do not believe that to be true.
There are currently two options:

A community can prohibit all Generative AI.
A community can require that all Generative AI be properly referenced.

Let's take a moment to remember how we got here.
When Generative AI became a problem, Stack Overflow and a number of sites responded with per-site policies to deal with it, including what content to allow and how to justify deleting it.
In response, the company created the self-admission policy. This policy overrode all site-specific policies. It also hamstrung the ability for moderators to remove generative AI, even if their communities wanted to prohibit it, as the only acceptable way to tell if content was produced using generative AI was if the poster explicitly admitted to it.
In the summer of 2023, moderators and curators across the network went on strike. One of the issues that led to this action was steps taken by the company that hamstrung efforts to moderate generative AI content. After discussions and negotiations, an agreement was reached, which led to work to better define network-wide standards and heuristics for dealing with generative AI.
As a result of the moderation strike, the self-admission policy was revoked and replaced with an interim policy. This interim policy was designed to allow communities to decide how to handle generative AI. If communities decided to prohibit generative AI or require some kind of attribution for generative AI, there were heuristics that moderators could use to justify deleting content and, if necessary, suspending users. The intent was to placate the communities and give time for a working group to develop a network-wide policy.
The final output was two policies. Each community was given a choice: allow Generative AI with appropriate referencing or prohibit Generative AI. A Help Center template was created for each option, and each community could indicate which version they wanted. Based on community response, an appropriate version was pushed to each site's Help Center. 27 sites in the network, including MSE, chose to adopt a policy that prohibited generative AI.
As an aside, I did not review the current state of the Help Center in these 27 sites, nor did I assess the network to see if any other sites adopted policies prohibiting generative AI. The number of sites with a policy banning generative AI may not be 27 today. This also means it is unclear which sites use the boilerplate template rolled out by SE and which sites have edited that template to be something else.
Moderators could edit the Help Center page to add details or clarity to help their community. This also allows the community to change their mind about which policy to implement. However, I do not believe that this editing was granted to enable communities to write their own policies. Instead, the editing was designed to allow communities to give relevant examples. For example, sites like Stack Overflow or Code Review have concerns about generated code that may not exist on sites like Cooking or Writing. Other communities may have their own unique considerations to help users understand what is permitted.
It's important to acknowledge the effort that went into creating the policies and drafting the two baseline Help Center articles. This was no small feat and it went through much discussion and several iterations involving moderators, power users, and community managers.
The discussions, drafting, and review of the two Help Center articles were colored by the problems that we saw.
The fundamental problem at the time was the generation of text. Some sites, like Stack Overflow, were being flooded with low-quality and often incorrect text and code produced by tools like ChatGPT. Words and phrases like "written by", "writes a response", "authentic text", and examples around large language models slipped into the drafts because they represented the problems that we saw and didn't fully reflect the scope of the community's thinking around generative AI. Image generation tools, like DALL-E and Midjourney, were available but did not cause an immediate problem on the network. Audio and video generation tools may have been available, but the network doesn't support directly posting this kind of content, and the tools weren't as widely accessible.
When analyzing the policies, we should look at the intent of the people who wrote them. The intent was to address all forms of generative AI and not require rehashing every time technology advanced. The problems people have with text, whether related to the quality of the content or the legality and ethics of the tools and use of their output, apply equally to text and images.

Should AI-generated imagery be allowed in posts on Meta SE?

Allowing AI-generated imagery requires allowing all forms of AI-generated content, assuming it is properly attributed and doesn't run afoul of the misleading information policy. So, the question is: Does the MSE community want to allow all generative AI?
The focus that we should have is on updating the standard text for the two Help Center templates and helping to roll those out across the network. This also includes finding sites that tailored those templates and removing any ambiguity. This is not a question of changing a site's policy unless they want to go from a prohibition on generative AI to allowing reference generative AI or vice-versa. This is a question of being explicitly clear about the network policy.
Meta SE adopting a unique policy is a dangerous road. Although each community needs to tailor its guidance to meet cultural norms, we need to consider that people participate across the network. Widely divergent policies cause friction as people try to participate on multiple sites. We must avoid fracturing the stance on generative AI from 2 overarching policies to dozens of overarching policies.

How does this answer the question of whether AI imagery should be allowed on Meta SE?

@Tinkeringbell Until we define a baseline network policy, how can any site tailor or tweak that policy for their context? I'm saying that you need to take a step back, revise the global policies, and then adjust what remains for MSE, if necessary. Anything else is wrong.

And I think my first paragraph explains this. If we don't or can't agree on what the current written policy means, how can we talk about changing it?

The question isn't asking for discussion on defining any networkwide baseline. Nor about adjusting global policies. It asks a pretty straightforward question of whether AI generated imagery should be allowed on this particular site and you're not answering it.

@Tinkeringbell Let me rephrase. What does the current policy say? Because I can tell you two things. First, I know how I interpret it. Second, I know that there are multiple other people, including network mods, who don't interpret it the same way I do. Until you define what the policy is right now and how to interpret the text on the Help Center page, how can there be any discussion of what it should be? There can't. You cannot talk about what should be unless and until you agree on what is.

For the record, I believe that the current policy already expressly prohibits posting any AI generated content, including images. However, the fact that there was a rollback war not decisively ended by moderators indicates that people disagree. Since moderators enforce the agreed upon policy, does that mean that the current written policy does not prohibit AI images?

The current policy for Meta SE can be interpreted both ways, that caused the rollback war and flags. We can very well define what it should be for Meta SE and make the help center match. The page is mod-editable. Again, I am not asking users to discuss how the current page should be interpreted. I'm asking them if they think AI generated images should be allowed on Meta SE, regardless of their own interpretation of the current help center page. There is no question here that is going to have any influence on help center pages networkwide at all.

Meta.SE in this case isn't going to define a networkwide policy, just like the rest of the network that doesn't use Meta.SE isn't going to define what Meta.SE's policy should be.

@tinkeringbell Again, you cannot define what should be unless you first specify what is. What is the current policy that users are expected to follow and moderators are expected to enforce based on the words in the Help Center? In order to have any conversation about that, you must answer that question. And, because the current wording in question is derived from the results of the strike negotiations and pushed to 27 sites, this question has current state implications for the network. It is impossible to answer your question until you answer mine.

Then you shouldn't have "answered" it. Like I said, your post isn't an answer to the question "Should AI generated imagery be allowed on Meta.SE". I believe you know, as do I, that if something is in your opinion wrong with a question, it goes in the comments there for the question to be improved. Not in the "answer" box. But given that there are plenty of other posts that do answer the question, your statement of it being impossible to answer it is verifiably false.

@Tinkeringbell You should know that answers are different on Meta. Especially when the question is tagged [tag:discussion]. I am engaging in discussion. In the future, this could be a valid question. However, it doesn't make sense to talk about this question without information. A policy was agreed upon already as a result of the strike negotiations. Without understanding what was agreed to then, I don't see how I can have an informed opinion about what any site's policy should be today.

A policy wasn't agreed upon "as a result of strike negotiations". That's BS: both MSE and IPS (and I think quite a few other sites, but I don't mod those so I don't know as clearly) had policies on text before the whole strike even happened, and those policies still stand. Mods just got a help center template that was pushed by staff to their sites if the communities wished so, together with an optional banner. But the policies that each community made before the strike still stand and weren't overridden because of it.

@Tinkeringbell I beg to differ. The agreed-upon text was pushed to the MSE Help Center. That became policy and overrode anything else unless and until the Help Center was edited to reflect the site's policies. The specific phrases that define the scope were not edited on MSE and a number of other sites and are therefore current policy. Defining what those words mean is crucial to this conversation. So, again, what is the current policy? Define what the written words mean. And be careful, because you're defining it for multiple sites now, because they all share the same words and phrases.

again, lies. I have messages in the MSE mod room reminding myself to edit the help center page on MSE because the version that was pushed didn't reflect site policy: it got the "attribution required version". Just because someone else posted the other template verbatim does not mean it can now not ever be edited in perpetuity to reflect what the community wants it to actually be. Again, just because the template is the same as on other sites, this is not a networkwide problem and you're not answering what the policy for Meta.SE should be.

@Tinkeringbell I'm disputing anything about being able to change policy. However, regardless of what you choose to believe, this is a network-wide problem. What is the current policy, today, on MSE about posting GenAI images? The answer to that question exists. There is a policy. It's in the Help Center. It exists in the Help Center of over 20 sites. Tell me what it is. Once you do that, I can tell you what the policy should be.

@Tinkeringbell The Strike negotiation results post, which was backed by an unprecedented level of community engagement, says that the original bans were superseded by company policy, which was then superseded by the negotiated policy. Per-site policies thereafter were mostly about whether or not they opted-in to the agreed policy or chose to leave it unmoderated. I see where you're coming from but Thomas isn't lying, he's reflecting the understanding of the situation that I think most people will have.

I feel like the context of the agreement was AI-generated text and it might not apply here, but Thomas is raising a very valid point. The amount of community effort that went into establishing the existing AI policies are massive. If we don't think they apply, we need to honor that effort by saying explicitly why we feel that way, and not just taking it for granted. The text may unfortunately be somewhat ambiguous because this issue wasn't top-of-mind at the time.

@2024-10-01 all I see linked there is an interim policy on AI detection, not on whether AI is considered allowed or banned. Nothing there overrides the previous discussions sites had on what they (dis)allow, it just outlines how these communities and their mods should go about detecting AI content and which "heuristics" count. It went from "you're only allowed to do live up to your community's wishes if the poster admits it is AI" to something more reasonable, but there is nothing there that made AI content on MSE or IPS suddenly "allowed" or overrode the agreement on not wanting AI (t)here

@Tinkeringbell Effective immediately, the interim standards that we have agreed on will serve as policy until a more permanent policy is established with the help of the broader community. The "more permanent policy" is the two options Help Center pages. I don't believe the intent was for any community to wholesale rewrite the policy, but to let moderators clarify one of the two options - GenAI content is allowed with references or GenAI content is prohibited. I believe that the policy applies to all GenAI. Which, IMO, makes this whole conversation moot. MSE decided to ban all GenAI content.

I don't think it's appropriate for MSE - or any site on the network - to introduce a third option, at least without the kind of community effort that went into the two existing options. But perhaps we need a third option: Ban GenAI text, allow referenced GenAI images/audio/video. I believe Cesar proposed this option.

@ThomasOwens I've seen the SO for Teams team working on "policy" for AI detection. Nothing in that statement says to me there will be new policy on whether content is allowed or not, all it says is that there will be more policy on how to detect content, and what can/can't be used as arguments to say something is or isn't AI. You can't just take that out of the context it is in and use it as an argument for way broader statements.

@Tinkeringbell Again, that is your opinion. The policy referred to both what content to allow and how to detect it. The thinking, both then and now, is that the community doesn't want GenAI of any kind on the network. Every site that is opted into the prohibition policy opted into a total, complete, ban on all forms of GenAI. Every community had a choice as to if they wanted to allow or disallow GenAI. I don't believe it's appropriate for any community, on their own, to invent a third choice.

@ThomasOwens at this point, yeah. Agree to disagree, this is "your opinion" too. I looked and cannot find a single sentence in https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391990/369802 or the strike negotiations results that I could quote, that would say allowing or disallowing text, images or whatever else an AI can come up with by a single community would fall afoul of that interim policy on detection as written. I'll reiterate this does not answer the question asked, and leave it at that.

@Tinkeringbell My opinion is backed by fact. The self-admission policy overrode all site policy - choosing to ban GenAI could only do so on self-admission. The interim policy replaced the self-admission policy and allowed sites to choose to ban GenAI based on certain heuristics until the working group finished their work. The final policy gave every site two options: ban GenAI or require GenAI to be referenced and gave mods heuristics for assessing GenAI.

Based on the wording of all three policies and the ongoing discussions, I fully believe that a site cannot choose to ban certain types of GenAI. There are only two options: ban GenAI or allow GenAI with appropriate referencing. A site cannot decide to allow unattributed GenAI. A site cannot choose to ban GenAI text and allow attributed GenAI images. Sites can't choose to allow abusive behavior, misleading information, or harmful political content, so why can a single site invent its own AI policy?

@ThomasOwens that's your interpretation of posts that you have convinced yourself are facts. Facts are that none of those ever overrode what sites wanted (yes or no AI), only how AI content could be moderated away if communities wanted to moderate it away. The final post you linked isn't even policy! It's not tagged and locked as such, it's just a post to discuss templates for help center articles, there's nothing binding there. You may have your beliefs but they again don't answer the question I asked and shouldn't be an "answer" here.

@Tinkeringbell Of course it's not tagged policy. The policy became one of the two Help Center pages! The page slug is even gen-ai-policy. MSE, as a community, is not allowed to invent a new policy option. There are only three options: (1) MSE holds the current policy. All GenAI is banned. (2) MSE changes policy. It allows for GenAI to be posted if it is referenced. (3) As a community across the entire network, we put the level of effort put into the current policy and give all communities more options and guidance for communicating those options.

Slug name means nothing to me, you're ascribing way too much value to it. It is linked in the help center as "What is this site’s policy on content generated by generative artificial intelligence tools?". Emphasis mine, it's only for this site. Just like /help/on-topic is also used quite a bit to describe what is also off-topic, if the slug were to be taken literally that shouldn't be there either then.

@MisterMiyagi You're right. It was written once, edited to address comments, a new version was added (leaving the original for easy viewing), edited more to address comments. It became messy. The new version is a unified approach that also explicitly answers the question.

@ThomasOwens It might be worth posting that as a separate answer, and leaving the old version for posterity.

@wizzwizz4 Eh. It's all in the edit history.
