# Does Stack Exchange Inc. intend to sue firms that use language models that are partly trained on Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, data-dump, chatgpt

Stack Exchange Inc. has [expressed an interest in financially profiting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390040/178179) from some companies that use Stack Exchange data to train their model.

Many language models are partly trained on Stack Exchange data. For example, the [LLaMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLaMA) 2 training set contain Stack Exchange data. Despite that, some of these language models claim to be usable commercially. E.g., [LLaMA 2](https://about.fb.com/news/2023/07/llama-2/):

> Llama 2 is free for research and commercial use.

Does Stack Exchange Inc. intend to sue firms that use these language models that are partly trained on Stack Exchange? If so, does Stack Exchange Inc. have some criteria on which companies to target? The criteria could be monthly active users (as done by Meta with LLaMA), company revenue or the percentage that Stack Exchange data represents compared to the entire training data.

Answer (score 7):

IANAL, but:

- The user-created content (questions, answers, comments, etc.) is primarily in [CC-BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/). See [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing) for the full details. Basically that means you *can* use the content for commercial purposes, with the requirements of Attribution (that's easy, and referencing [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com) or similar is a lot easier than referencing thousands of individual users) and Share Alike. I do *not* know how Share Alike would apply when an AI program is trained on a big blob of data. But it should be allowed, even if it is used commercially.
- As far as SE trying to make money off of the data, that makes sense too. While SE provides all the data through various methods for free, it is certainly quite plausible that SE could package the data in a more usable form for a fee, whether one-time or an ongoing subscription. They could also include information that is *not* necessarily under CC-BY-SA - e.g., posts from Stack Overflow for Teams (with appropriate licensing/permission from the Teams customers), voting information - e.g., answers that are highly ranked by users could be weighted in an AI training system, etc.